# Angular 2.x change <title> in head (outside my app)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I think it should be easy but I cannot find how.

I have something like

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>{{'a' + 'b'}}</title>
</head>
<body>
  <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

It seems like I cannot access anything outside `my-app`.

In angular 1.x it was easy, I was able to add `ng-app` on any element (`<html ng-app="myApp">`).

Now I think I'm able only bootstrap in body.

I know I can manually bootstrap somehow (didn't try yet), but dynamically change title in single page applications should be super-easy, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Angular2 can't be bootstrapped to entire html. But you can use [Title Service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform/browser/Title-class.html).

> A service that can be used to get and set the title of a current HTML document.

It has 2 methods:

```
getTitle()

setTitle()
```

Don't forget to check the [dependency injection](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html) section out to see how you can use the services.

EDIT:

As of the release (2.0.0), this is how you can do it:

```
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';

export class SomeComponent {
  constructor(title: Title) {
    // title.getTitle();
    // title.setTitle('new title');
  }
}
```

And the docs for the `Title` service are now here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/Title-class.html

Comment: Thanks, you answered my question. But the problem is that I actually have other problem. I just tried to ask more common question. Can you take a look at my real problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34430666/angular-2-x-bind-class-on-body-tag