# Angular 2.x bind class on body tag

Tags: javascript, angular

Since Angular 2.x is bootstrapped inside a body how do I add `[class.fixed]="isFixed"` on body tag (outside my-app)?

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body [class.fixed]="isFixed">
  <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

My app component looks like

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/common';
import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router, Location} from 'angular2/router';
import {About} from './components/about/about';
import {Test} from './components/test/test';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    providers: [],
    templateUrl: '/views/my-app.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES],
    pipes: []
})

@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/about', name: 'About', component: About, useAsDefault: true},
    {path: '/test', name: 'Test', component: Test}
])

export class MyApp {
    router: Router;
    location: Location;

    constructor(router: Router, location: Location) {
        this.router = router;
        this.location = location;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried just using `"body"` as selector of your application component?

Comment: Thank you, just tried but without success. App still works but I think it only bootstraps inside `body` without `body` itself. If I change selector to `html` - it replaces my head and body with template of component..

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using `<body>` as app component works fine but you can't use binding on the `<body>` tag because it attempts to bind `"isFixed" to the parent and there is no parent.

Use `@HostBinding` instead

```
@Component(
  selector: 'body',
  templateUrl: 'app_element.html'
)
class AppElement {
  @HostBinding('class.fixed') 
  bool isFixed = true;
}
```

This is Dart code but it shouldn't be hard to translate it to TS.

See also [@HostBinding and @HostListener: what do they do and what are they for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37965647/hostbinding-and-hostlistening-what-do-they-do-and-what-are-they-for)

You can always use plain JS to update the DOM if you don't depend on server side rendering or web workers.

Alternatively you can just use

```
document.body.classList.add('foo');
```

Comment: I think it could be a solution but I cannot make even simplest example working with HostBinding.. do you have a link to any example?.. Example from angular.io/docs doesn't work for me..

Comment: I work only with Dart and I tried it and it worked for me. Can you create a Plunker from your example and we try to figure out why it's not working?

Comment: I got HostBinding working but I will not use it this time. I'll just add class on body in some cases. But I can't select elements with angular 2 (or I don't know how). @Günter Zöchbauer can you look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34432980/angular-2-x-selecting-dom-element
Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working. I think the other question is something that is quite different in Dart, therefore I can't help you there.

Comment: the link is broken

Comment: @StepanSuvorov thanks for the hint. There is no example in the new docs link anymore :-/ I added a link to another answer that has more explanation instead.

Comment: I don't know to what extend this is a good solution as it will replace the whole body and so remove all the <script> tags. Anyone knows?