# Angular 2.x selecting DOM element

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I know it should be easy but angular 2.0 has no many examples yet..

In one of my components in some case I need to add class on my body tag. But my application is bootstrapped deeper than body, so I need something like

```
angular.element('body').addClass('fixed');
```

but in Angular 2.0..

BTW, I know I can somehow bootstrap my application to include `body` tag, but I think in some other cases I would need to select some elements anyway, so I need a solution how to do this simple task - "select element and add class to it"

Comment: `angular.element(document.querySelector('body')).addClass('fixed');`

Comment: But in angular 2.0 I don't have `angular` object, do I?

Comment: `document.querySelector('body').className += ' fixed';`

Comment: Components should ideally be hermetic, they should only affect themselves and their children. I get the use case, but think carefully if it is absolutely neccesary.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update**

I'm not sure if `DOM` is actually still supported in RC. The related statements aren't very clear. Something like

> `DOM` is only for internal use. Either access the DOM directly or use a custom renderer.

I haven't see how a custom renderer might be implemented or how to provide an implementation depending on the current platform (webworker, server, DOM thread).

**Update**
This seems to be the Angular2 way

```
import { DOM } from 'angular2/src/platform/dom/dom_adapter';

DOM.addClass(DOM.query("body"), 'fixed');
```

**Import from `.../src/...` at your own risk. `.../src/...` is considered private implementation and you can't expect any guarantees that the API won't change without notice.**

I tried it in Dart and it works fine (not sure if the TS import above is correct though). In Dart `DOM` is exported by `package:angular2/angular2.dart`

**Original**

If you want to access a DOM element that's outside of your Angular application root, just use [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), no need to involve Angular.

Comment: But angular 1.x had jquery lite or something to help with adding/removing class. Does angular 2.0 has something like jqlite to help with adding/removing classes for elements outside application root?

Comment: I don't think so. Angular2 is all about avoiding direct DOM access to ensure everything is working with webworkers and server-side rendering.

Comment: Thanks for this hint. I ended up doing the following:

    `ngOnInit() {
        var dom = new BrowserDomAdapter();
        dom.addClass(dom.query("body"), "login-content");
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        var dom = new BrowserDomAdapter();
        dom.removeClass(dom.query("body"), "login-content");
    }`

Comment: In beta7 the import is now `import { BrowserDomAdapter } from 'angular2/platform/browser';` See available methods here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform/browser/BrowserDomAdapter-class.html

Answer (score 9):

As of Angular2 Version 2.0.0-beta.17.

[Attribute Directives](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html) in Angular2 will do this for you nicely.

Please see this [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/8uMBMinR6usJT4HE0QYA) written in TypeScript. This does what you want nicely.

The directive file `my-highlight.ts` has the line:

```
this.renderer.setElementClass(this.element, "red", true);
```

This sets the CSS class on the element.

While `template.html` has the actual element which is decorated with the directive `[myHighlight]`:

```
<p [myHighlight]>Mouseover to highlight me!</p>
```

This, to me, provides the least hack-ish answer to the question without any dependency on jqLite.

Comment: I don't see how this is related to the question to add a class to elements outside Angulars root component. What this tutorial shows is actually bad practice. See also https://github.com/angular/angular.io/issues/1670. If you think you must use `ElementRef.nativeElement` then use it with `Renderer` like shown in http://stackoverflow.com/a/34573219/217408 instead of directly calling methods on it.

Comment: Thank you for the link to the other post using renderer, this looks interesting. I am going by the latest Angular2 documentation, if that changes I will update my plunk. I still feel this is a good answer as the question states they want to "select element and add class to it". I will update my answer to edit the "class" attribute instead of "style".

Comment: In my opinion It still doesn't fit to the question because it doesn't allow to set the attribute on the `<body>` element. This is not too obvious from the question though.

Comment: Yes I see the body tag in the question now. I think my answer may help people who want to select any other DOM element though.

Comment: I have updated my answer to change the CSS class. I have added the renderer to do this also. I would very much like to leave this answer here, because it was this specific problem that lead me here, I believe others may find this useful.

Comment: Sure, no prob.  . . . .

Answer (score 6):

As of `angular 2.4` you should inject the `DOCUMENT` and don't interact with any adapter:

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({})
export class MyClass {

    constructor (@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document) { }

    doSomething() {
        this.document.someMethodOfDocument();
    }
}
```

Further reading: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8509

Answer (score 3):

**DOM Manipulation in Angular 2 / 4 app**

To manipulate the DOM in Angular 2/4 apps, we need to `implement` the method `ngAfterViewInit()` of `AfterViewInit`. The method `ngAfterViewInit()` is called when the bindings of the children directives have been checked for the first time. In other words, **when** the view is initially rendered.

The `@ViewChild` provides access to `nativeElement`. It is recommended to not access `nativeElement` inside the `ngAfterViewInit()` because it is not browser safe. Also, it's not supported by web workers. Web workers will never know when the DOM updates.

The right way is to use `renderer`. The renderer needs to be injected to the component constructor. We need to provide an `id` reference to the `HTML` element on the view something like this:

`<p #p1></p>`

It shall be accessed by the corresponding coponent `.ts` file, something like this:

```
export class SampleComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild("p1") p1;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) //Renderer set to be depreciated soon
  { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {

    //recommended DOM manipulation approach
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.p1.nativeElement, //setElementStyle for soon to be depreciate Renderer
      'color',
      'red');

    //not recommended DOM manipulation approach
    //this.p1.nativeElement.style = "color:blue;";
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend direct DOM access from Angular, but you have a DOM hook via the ElementRef of your component. Once you have access to it you can use it directly or via jquery or any other DOM manipulation technique. I have included an example of how to use jquery to run general queries. If you are always going for the body tag you don't really need ElementRef, but it's useful for something that is relative to the root of the component.

```
import {Component, ElementRef, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

declare var jQuery:any;

@Component({
    selector: 'jquery-integration',
    templateUrl: './components/jquery-integration/jquery-integration.html'
})
export class JqueryIntegration implements OnInit {
    elementRef: ElementRef;

    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find('.moving-box').draggable({containment:'#draggable-parent'});
    }
}
```

More info here: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/using-jquery-with-angular-2.0

Demo: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/angular-2-samples/#/demo/jquery

Comment: You should really try NOT to use jQuery. Its really not need w/ modern dom traversal and standardization and ng2 provides a lot of the functions you might need that browser doesn't have

Comment: @amcdnl Can you provide an example of how to access an element with a class ".moving-box" as shown in the code above?

Comment: elementRef.nativeElement.getElementsByClass

Comment: @juanpastas How does it have no conventions when there's a style guide for it, and it's literally the same 3 files (html/style/typescript) over and over again basically. Try the Angular CLI, it'll make life easier for you as well.