# Focus on newly added input element

Tags: angular

I have a new Angular 2 app with a list of `input` boxes. When the user hits the return key, I add a new `input` box immediately after the one they're currently editing. Or rather, I (asynchronously) add a new entry to the array in the model, which causes Angular 2 to automatically generate a new `input` box in the near future.

How can I make it so that `input` focus changes to the newly added element automatically?

**EDIT 1:**
Alternatively, I get a reference to the model object that's causing the DOM to be generated. From the component code, is there a way to search for a DOM element representing a particular model object?

**EDIT 2:**
Here's my code to just make this work. Hopefully this is offensive enough to some Angular 2 devs to encourage a reply :-)

```
app.WordComponent = ng.core
    .Component({
        selector: 'word-editor',
        template:'<input type="text" [value]="word.word" (input)="word.update($event.target.value)" (keydown)="keydown($event)"/>',
        styles:[
            ''
        ],
        properties:[
            'list:list',
            'word:word'
        ]
    })
    .Class({
        constructor:[
            function() {
            }
        ],
        keydown:function(e) {
            if(e.which == 13) {
                var ul = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
                var childCount = ul.childNodes.length;

                this.list.addWord("").then(function(word) {
                    var interval = setInterval(function() {
                        if(childCount < ul.childNodes.length) {
                            ul.lastChild.querySelector('input').focus();
                            clearInterval(interval);
                        }
                    }, 1);
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Your `setInterval` should most likely just be a `setTimeout`.

Comment: Whoever visiting this answer, have a look at this. https://github.com/spirosikmd/angular2-focus
Quite easy to use. This does it all easily if you're using *ngFor

Comment: So easy you need an external lib ??

Answer (score 104, accepted):

If I'm allowed to do so, I will take part of @Sasxa answer and modify it to make it more like what you're looking for.

A few changes

- I will use a `ngFor` so angular2 adds the new input instead of doing it myself. The main purpose is just to make angular2 to iterate over it.
- Instead of `ViewChild` I'm going to use `ViewChildren` that returns a [QueryList](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/core/linker/query_list.ts) which has a [`changes`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/core/linker/query_list.ts#L34) property. This property is an Observable and it returns the elements after they've changed.

Since in ES5, we have no decorators we have to use the `queries` property to use `ViewChildren`

**Component**

```
Component({
    selector: 'cmp',
    template : `
        <div>
            // We use a variable so we can query the items with it
            <input #input (keydown)="add($event)" *ngFor="#input of inputs">
        </div>
    `,
    queries : {
        vc : new ng.core.ViewChildren('input')
    }
})
```

**Focus** on the last element.

```js
ngAfterViewInit: function() {

    this.vc.changes.subscribe(elements => {
        elements.last.nativeElement.focus();
    });

}
```

Like I said before, ViewChildren returns a QueryList which contains `changes` property. When we subscribe to it everytime it changes it will return the list of elements. The list `elements` contains a `last` property (among others) that in this case returns the last element, we use `nativeElement` on it and finally `focus()`

**Add input elements** This is for pure convenince, the inputs array has no real purpose more than redraw the `ngFor`.

```js
add: function(key) {
    if(key.which == 13) {
        // See plnkr for "this.inputs" usage
        this.inputs.push(this.inputs.length+1);
    }
}
```

We push a *dummy* item on the array so it redraws.

Example using ES5 : http://plnkr.co/edit/DvtkfiTjmACVhn5tHGex

Example using ES6/TS : http://plnkr.co/edit/93TgbzfPCTxwvgQru2d0?p=preview

## Update 29/03/2016

Time has passed, things have been clarified and there are always best practices to learn/teach. I've simplified this answer by changing a few things

- Instead of using `@ViewChildren` and subscribing to it I made a Directive that will be instatiated everytime a new input is created
- I'm using `Renderer` to make it WebWorker safe. The original answer accesses `focus()` directly on the `nativeElement` which is discouraged.
- Now I listen to `keydown.enter` which simplifies the key down event, I don't have to check `which` value.

To the point. The component looks like (simplified, full code on the plnkrs below)

```js
@Component({
  template: `<input (keydown.enter)="add()" *ngFor="#input of inputs">`,
})

add() {
    this.inputs.push(this.inputs.length+1);
}
```

And the directive

```js
@Directive({
  selector : 'input'
})
class MyInput {
  constructor(public renderer: Renderer, public elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(
      this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'focus', []);
  }
}
```

As you can see I'm calling `invokeElementMethod` to trigger `focus` on the element instead of accessing it directly.

This version is much cleaner and safer than the original one.

**plnkrs updated to beta 12**

Example using ES5 : http://plnkr.co/edit/EpoJvff8KtwXRnXZJ4Rr

Example using ES6/TS : http://plnkr.co/edit/em18uMUxD84Z3CK53RRe

## Update 2018

`invokeElementMethod` is deprecated. Use Renderer2 instead of Renderer.

Give your element an id, and you can use [selectRootElement](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2#selectRootElement):

```
this.renderer2.selectRootElement('#myInput').focus();
```

Comment: Very elegant.  I'm surprised that we can use the same local template variable name/identifier -- `#input` -- on multiple elements.

Comment: I would rename the `ngFor` local template variable something else, so that it doesn't look like it is related to the other `#input`:  `*ngFor="#in of inputs"`.

Comment: Instead of adding an event handler to every `input`, I suggest putting it on the `div` and letting the event bubble up: `<div (keydown)="add($event)">  <input #input *ngFor="#in of inputs">`.

Comment: For the 2018 update, instead of using an ID, I found this to work:
`this.renderer2.selectRootElement(this.elementRef.nativeElement).focus();`

Answer (score 42):

Take a look at [ViewChild](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ViewChild-var.html), here's a [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/xL3Odd2esXCTpGJmmlHU).
This might be what you're looking for:

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <input #name>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: []
})
export class App {

  @ViewChild('name') vc: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.vc.nativeElement.focus();
  }
}
```

Comment: still good in Angular 6 and omitting "ElementRef" ViewChild type declaration not a problem or for the vscode linter

Comment: The only code that worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 27):

With inline angular code, focus after conditional paint:

```
  <span *ngIf="editId==item.id">
    <input #taskEditText type="text" [(ngModel)]="editTask" (keydown.enter)="save()" (keydown.esc)="saveCancel()"/>
    <button (click)="save()">Save</button>
    <button (click)="saveCancel()">Cancel</button>
    {{taskEditText.focus()}}
  </span>
```

Answer (score 9):

You can implement a simple input text directive, so that whenever a new input is created, it will auto focus itself. The `focus()` method is called inside of the `ngAfterViewInit()` component lifecycle hook after the view is fully initialized.

```
@Directive({
    selector: 'input[type=text]'
})
export class FocusInput implements AfterViewInit {
    private firstTime: bool = true;
    constructor(public elem: ElementRef) {
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
      if (this.firstTime) {
        this.elem.nativeElement.focus();
        this.firstTime = false;
      }
    }
}
```

Use the `FocusInput` directive in your component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    directives: [FocusInput],
    template: `<input type="text" (keyup.enter)="last ? addNewWord():0" 
                *ngFor="#word of words; #last = last" [value]="word.word" 
                #txt (input)="word.word = txt.value" />{{words |json}}`
})
export class AppComponent {
    words: Word[] = [];
    constructor() {
        this.addNewWord();
    }
    addNewWord() {
        this.words.push(new Word());
    }
}
```

Note the following:

1. The `(keyup.enter)` event is used to detect when the <enter> key is pressed
2. `ngFor` is used to repeat the input element for each word from the array of `words`
3. `last` is a Boolean bound to a local variable which is true when the input is the last one
4. The keyup event is bound to the expression `last ? addNewWord() : 0`. This ensures that a new input field is only added when the <enter> key is pressed from the last Input

[Demo Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/pDDEB7tyHrWZBXV8vFJz?p=preview)

Comment: Very nice, after trying out all the above answers this one worked for me! `Anguler 5` Thanks!!

Comment: This is the most solid solution in my opinion

Answer (score 3):

In order to prioritize which element will get focus when initializing several directives in same cycle, use:

**Directive:**

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[focusOnInit]'
})
export class FocusOnInitDirective implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @Input('focusOnInit') priority: number = 0;

  static instances: FocusOnInitDirective[] = [];

  constructor(public renderer: Renderer, public elementRef: ElementRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    FocusOnInitDirective.instances.push(this)
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      FocusOnInitDirective.instances.splice(FocusOnInitDirective.instances.indexOf(this), 1);
    });

    if (FocusOnInitDirective.instances.every((i) => this.priority >= i.priority)) {
      this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(
        this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'focus', []);
    }
  }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
<input type="text" focusOnInit="9">
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/T9VDPIWrVSZ6MpXCdlXF

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use tabindex instead?