# focus input field on value change? angular2

Tags: angular

I have an input field that adds class active when modalOpen = true, and this works fine.

However, i want it to focus on the input field when this modal shows?

```
 <div [class.active]="modalOpen">
     <input>
 </div>
```

Comment: Looks like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34522306/angular-2-focus-on-newly-added-input-element

Answer (score 5):

Add a local template variable to your input element: `<input #input1>`, and get a reference to it using `@ViewChild('input1') input1ElementRef;`.

Then, wherever you are setting `modalOpen` to `true`, also set focus on the input element with `this._renderer.invokeElementMethod(this.input1ElementRef.nativeElement, 'focus', [])`.  
Using Renderer is web worker safe.

```
import {Component, ViewChild, Renderer} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-comp',
  template: `<div [class.active]="modalOpen">
       <input #input1>
     </div>
     <button (click)="showModal()">show modal</button>`
})
export class MyComponent {
  @ViewChild('input1') input1ElementRef;
  modalOpen = false;
  constructor(private _renderer:Renderer) {}
  showModal() {
    this.modalOpen = true;
    // give Angular a chance to create or show the modal
    setTimeout( _ => 
      this._renderer.invokeElementMethod(
        this.input1ElementRef.nativeElement, 'focus', []);
    );
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<my-comp></my-comp>`,
  directives: [MyComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() { console.clear(); }
}
```

<kbd>[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qZszTBnfUD8sDYgoPerF?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks! I've been looking exactly for this - I wanted to focus an input when I click a button.

Answer (score 1):

I have a sample component where I set focus when an element comes "active".
Here is my approach:

```
export class Spreadsheet implements AfterViewChecked{

    ngAfterViewChecked(){
        //some logic to find "active" element 
        let cell = document.getElementById(this.model.current.rowIndex + '-' + this.model.current.columnIndex);
        cell.focus();
    }
}
```

More here:
http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/virtualized-spreadsheet-component-in-angular-2.0

http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/angular-2-samples/#/demo/spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" #myInput />
{{ myInput.focus() }}
```

Just add **{{ myInput.focus() }}** right after input inside template