# Angular2: focus a control

Tags: angular

In an Angular2 form submit handler, I have to perform some custom validation. When validation fails, I add the error to the control using …

```
this.controlname.setErrors({'errorname': true});
```

This works, but I would also like to focus the control. (Primarily, because the errors are styled in a way that they appear only for the focussed control.)

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: Looks like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34522306/angular-2-focus-on-newly-added-input-element

Comment: OK, thanks – will look into it. When searching for existing questions, my search was obviously too generic, using only “control”, not “input” ;-)

Comment: I knew it was there, this helps ;-)