# Angular2 - Focusing a textbox on component load

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I am developing a component in Angular2 (Beta 8). The component has a textbox and a dropdown. I would like to set the focus in textbox as soon as component is loaded or on change event of dropdown. How would I achieve this in angular2. Following is Html for the component.

```html
<div>
    <form role="form" class="form-horizontal ">        
        <div [ngClass]="{showElement:IsEditMode, hidden:!IsEditMode}">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-1 col-sm-1" for="name">Name</label>
                <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7">
                    <input id="name" type="text" [(ngModel)]="person.Name" class="form-control" />

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                    <input type="button" value="Add" (click)="AddPerson()" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div [ngClass]="{showElement:!IsEditMode, hidden:IsEditMode}">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-1 col-sm-1" for="name">Person</label>
                <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7">
                    <select [(ngModel)]="SelectedPerson.Id"  (change)="PersonSelected($event.target.value)" class="form-control">
                        <option *ngFor="#item of PeopleList" value="{{item.Id}}">{{item.Name}}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>        
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 88, accepted):

This answer is inspired by post  [Angular 2: Focus on newly added input element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34522306/angular-2-focus-on-newly-added-input-element)

Steps to set the focus on Html element in Angular2

1. Import ViewChildren in your Component

   ```
   import { Input, Output, AfterContentInit, ContentChild,AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ViewChildren } from 'angular2/core';
   ```
2. Declare local template variable name for the html for which you want to set the focus
3. Implement the function  ngAfterViewInit()  or other appropriate life cycle hooks
4. Following is the piece of code which I used for setting the focus

   ```
   ngAfterViewInit() {vc.first.nativeElement.focus()}
   ```
5. Add `#input` attribute to the DOM element you want to access.

```js
///This is typescript
import {Component, Input, Output, AfterContentInit, ContentChild,
  AfterViewChecked, AfterViewInit, ViewChild,ViewChildren} from 'angular2/core';

export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit,AfterViewChecked { 
   @ViewChildren('input') vc;
  
   ngAfterViewInit() {            
        this.vc.first.nativeElement.focus();
    }
  
 }
```

```html
<div>
    <form role="form" class="form-horizontal ">        
        <div [ngClass]="{showElement:IsEditMode, hidden:!IsEditMode}">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-1 col-sm-1" for="name">Name</label>
                <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7">
                    <input #input id="name" type="text" [(ngModel)]="person.Name" class="form-control" />

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                    <input type="button" value="Add" (click)="AddPerson()" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div [ngClass]="{showElement:!IsEditMode, hidden:IsEditMode}">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-1 col-sm-1" for="name">Person</label>
                <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7">
                    <select [(ngModel)]="SelectedPerson.Id"  (change)="PersonSelected($event.target.value)" class="form-control">
                        <option *ngFor="#item of PeopleList" value="{{item.Id}}">{{item.Name}}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>        
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Simple enough, but what happens if you need to set focus in another component? For example, default search box (in a header) from a child component.

Comment: How about dynamically generated element?

Comment: Using Angular Material I needed to include `ChangeDetectorRef` in the constructor and then call `this.cd.detectChanges();` after the focus call, per [this answer by @jspassov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54794081/1450420).

Answer (score 89):

Using simple `autofocus` HTML5 attribute works for 'on load' scenario

```
 <input autofocus placeholder="enter text" [(ngModel)]="test">
```

or

```
<button autofocus (click)="submit()">Submit</button>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_input_autofocus.asp

Comment: This only seems to work if you refresh the page or load the page from scratch. If you navigate to the form component via router, the field doesn't get selected.

Comment: this is not a good solution when we have multiple components, this will work for the first default component only

Comment: +1 - Thank You Nikhil, it is perfect ; I use it this way: <div class=" or-name uk-tile-muted uk-text-left uk-display-block" *ngIf="value!==cHttpUser">{{value.name}} </div> <input class="uk-input uk-form-controls-text or-input" *ngIf="value===cHttpUser" [(ngModel)]="value.name" autofocus (click)="update()" (keyup.enter)="update()" (keyup.tab)="update()" (blur)=" update()">: click on div, input below get the focus at once, before not. Had to click again to get in and type, it was an "half way". One click left!

Answer (score 35):

```
<input id="name" type="text" #myInput />
{{ myInput.focus() }}
```

this is the best and simplest way, because **code "myInput.focus()" runs after input created**

WARNING: this solution is acceptable only if you have single element in the form (user will be not able to select other elements)

Comment: Lol that actually works! A bit hacky but very simple and functional, thanks!:)

Comment: I liked it a lot at first, but it seems like it always keeps me from selecting other elements (or even highlighting text to copy). Had to switch to the accepted answer here with view children.

Comment: it work fine in case there is the only one input on the page

Comment: yep, this method acceptable if there only one edit on the screen. it prevents from setting focus on any other inputs!

Comment: Note that the myInput.focus() method will be firing on every change cycle. This can cause unwanted behaviour like @JasonW stated.

Comment: very bad solution, it will execute again and again, as well as the user will be not able to select anything on the page because it's focusing on the textbox on every change cycle as @SergeyGurin mentioned.

Comment: hidden gem!!:) You rock my friend!

Answer (score 29):

The original question asked for a way to set focus initially, OR to set focus later, in response to an event. It seems like the correct way to approach this is to make an attribute directive which can be set for any input element, and then to use a custom event to safely trigger the focus method on this input element. To to so, first create the directive:

```
import { Directive, Input, EventEmitter, ElementRef, Renderer, Inject } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[focus]'
})
export class FocusDirective {
    @Input('focus') focusEvent: EventEmitter<boolean>;

    constructor(@Inject(ElementRef) private element: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.focusEvent.subscribe(event => {
            this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(this.element.nativeElement, 'focus', []);
        });
    }
}
```

Note that it uses renderer.invokeElementMethod on the nativeElement, which is web worker safe. Notice also that focusEvent is declared as an input.

Then add the following declarations to the Angular 2 component which has the template where you wish to use the new directive to set focus to an input element:

```
public focusSettingEventEmitter = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

ngAfterViewInit() { // ngOnInit is NOT the right lifecycle event for this.
    this.focusSettingEventEmitter.emit(true);
}
setFocus(): void {
  this.focusSettingEventEmitter.emit(true);
}
```

Don't forget to import EventEmitter above the component like this:

```
import { Component, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
```

and in the template for this component, set the new [focus] attribute like this:

```
<input id="name" type="text" name="name" 
    [(ngModel)]="person.Name" class="form-control"
    [focus]="focusSettingEventEmitter">
```

Finally, in your module, import and declare the new directive like this:

```
import { FocusDirective } from './focus.directive';

@NgModule({
    imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
    declarations: [AppComponent, AnotherComponent, FocusDirective ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
```

To recap: the ngAfterViewInit function will cause the new EventEmitter to emit, and since we assigned this emitter to the [focus] attribute in the input element in our template, and we declared this EventEmitter as an input to the new directive and invoked the focus method in the arrow function that we passed to the subscription to this event, the input element will receive focus after the component is initialized, and whenever setFocus is called.

I had the same need in my own app, and this worked as advertised. Thank you very much to the following: http://blog.thecodecampus.de/angular-2-set-focus-element/

Comment: This is great and it works, but I wonder if it's just a teeny bit too much work for a minor focusing. I was going to do it as a nice thing for the user as it's not a requirement, but it seems like an excessive amount of code for saving the user a single click.

Comment: @KentWeigel - This is a really classy solution and works perfectly. It's the 'right' answer imo. Thanks.

Comment: this is really nice solution, but you did not use the `setFocus` function

Answer (score 6):

See [Angular 2: Focus on newly added input element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34522306/angular-2-focus-on-newly-added-input-element) for how to set the focus.

For "on load" use the `ngAfterViewInit()` lifecycle callback.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Link you shared was quite helpful. +1 for this. Will share the answer for this particular scenario.

Answer (score 2):

I had a slightly different problem. I worked with inputs in a **modal** and it drove me mad. No of the proposed solutions worked for me.

Until i found this issue: https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/1597

This good guy gave me the hint that **ngx-bootstrap modal** has a focus configuration. If this configuration is not set to false, the modal will be focused after the animation and there is NO WAY to focus anything else.

**Update:**

To set this configuration, add the following attribute to the modal div:

```
[config]="{focus: false}"
```

**Update 2:**

To force the focus on the input field i wrote a directive and set the focus in every AfterViewChecked cycle as long as the input field has the class ng-untouched.

```
 ngAfterViewChecked() {
    // This dirty hack is needed to force focus on an input element of a modal.
    if (this.el.nativeElement.classList.contains('ng-untouched')) {
        this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(this.el.nativeElement, 'focus', []);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @FireGnome, could you share where to configure this?

Comment: as you can see here: 

http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals#static

there is a configuration attribute [config]="{backdrop: 'static'}"
You can set there the property focus: false

Comment: Hi, I am having the same issue, I have added the ngx modal and  configuration and tried to add focus with a directive( no luck as yet ), what did you use to add focus to the input each time ? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Also, it can be done dynamically like so...

```
<input [id]="input.id" [type]="input.type" [autofocus]="input.autofocus" />
```

> Where input is

```
const input = {
  id: "my-input",
  type: "text",
  autofocus: true
};
```

Comment: The opposite didn't work for me `[autofocus]="false"`

Comment: In your case it would be autofocus=“false”; the [] are only for evaluations like “myObj.key”. You’re using an actual string.

Answer (score 2):

Directive for autoFocus first field

```js
import {
  Directive,
  ElementRef,
  AfterViewInit
} from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: "[appFocusFirstEmptyInput]"
})
export class FocusFirstEmptyInputDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const invalidControl = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector(".ng-untouched");
    if (invalidControl) {
      invalidControl.focus();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have much luck with many of these solutions on all browsers.  This is the solution that worked for me.

For router changes:

```
router.events.subscribe((val) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (this.searchElement) {
            this.searchElement.nativeElement.focus();
        }
    }, 1);
})
```

Then `ngAfterViewInit()` for the onload scenario.

Answer (score -1):

you can use $ (jquery) :

```
<div>
    <form role="form" class="form-horizontal ">        
        <div [ngClass]="{showElement:IsEditMode, hidden:!IsEditMode}">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-1 col-sm-1" for="name">Name</label>
                <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7">
                    <input id="txtname`enter code here`" type="text" [(ngModel)]="person.Name" class="form-control" />

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                    <input type="button" value="Add" (click)="AddPerson()" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div [ngClass]="{showElement:!IsEditMode, hidden:IsEditMode}">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-1 col-sm-1" for="name">Person</label>
                <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7">
                    <select [(ngModel)]="SelectedPerson.Id"  (change)="PersonSelected($event.target.value)" class="form-control">
                        <option *ngFor="#item of PeopleList" value="{{item.Id}}">{{item.Name}}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>        
    </form>
</div>
```

then in ts :

```
    declare var $: any;

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-my-comp',
      templateUrl: './my-comp.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./my-comp.component.css']
    })
    export class MyComponent  {

    @ViewChild('loadedComponent', { read: ElementRef, static: true }) loadedComponent: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;

    setFocus() {
    const elem = this.loadedComponent.nativeElement.querySelector('#txtname');
          $(elem).focus();
    }
    }
```

Comment: +1 for the only one using @ViewChild, but you don't need jquery if you're already got a reference to the element (or it's container).