# set focus on mdl-textfield after reload

Tags: angular2-mdl

I'm using the autofocus attribute for mdl-textfield, however after navigating to another page and returning to the target page, the focus on mdl-textfield is lost.

I tried this approach:
[Angular2 - Focusing a textbox on component load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35790021/angular2-focusing-a-textbox-on-component-load).

However it valid only for DOM elements such as .

I undrestood that if i want to get focus after navigating away and returning, I have to do it on ngAfterViewInit() method?

Any help, How can i do that?

Thanks

Comment: the MdlTextFieldComponent has a setFocus() method you don't need the native element to set the focus. example: https://github.com/mseemann/angular2-mdl/tree/master/src/demo-app/app/textfield

Comment: Thanks, I figured out how by using setFocus method inside ngAfterViewInit() . Thanks :)