# Focus an <input> element

Tags: angular

I've many `input` boxes in a `div` and I need to focus one of them programmatically.

How to do it?

It's something like:

```
<div>
<input type="text" name="txt1" />
<input type="text" name="txt2" />
<input type="text" name="txt3" />
<input type="text" name="txt4" />
<input type="text" name="txt5" />
<input type="text" name="txt6" />
</div>
<button (click)="selectSample()" />

selectSample() {
    ?????????('txt3').focus();
    console.log('Button pressed, txt3 has been selected');
}
```

Comment: try to take reference using java script like `document.getElementByid('')` or post some code to make it more clear

Comment: Looks like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34522306/angular-2-focus-on-newly-added-input-element/34573219#34573219

Comment: Check also my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42745350/3170087). It isn't dependent on component where you want to use it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
<div>
<input #input type="text" name="txt1" />
<input #input type="text" name="txt2" />
<input #input type="text" name="txt3" />
<input #input type="text" name="txt4" />
<input #input type="text" name="txt5" />
<input #input type="text" name="txt6" />
</div>
<button (click)="selectSample()">click</button>
`
})
export class App {
  @ViewChildren('input') inputs;

  selectSample() {
    // console.debug(this.inputs.toArray().find((e) => {
    //  return e.nativeElement.getAttribute('name') == 'txt3';
    //}).nativeElement.value);

    this.inputs.toArray().find((e) => {
      return e.nativeElement.getAttribute('name') == 'txt3';
    }).nativeElement.focus();

  }
}
```

[Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/irWKmO?p=preview)

Comment: ViewChildren(input) inputs; <-- input not defined

Comment: Thanks, I discovered it while building the Plunker. If you know in advance (build time) you want `<input name="txt3">` then @PierreDuc s approach is the better one. If you dynamically want to choose one based on the name, my approach might work better.

Comment: Yes...It's must be dynamic, so your approach is more appropriated. I just used txt3 as sample.

Comment: That's what I assumed :)

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at the [`ViewChild`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ViewChild-var.html) (and [`ViewChildren`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ViewChildren-var.html) like Gunter suggests) annotations.

You can do something like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'samples',
  template: `
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="txt1">
      <input type="text" name="txt2">
      <input type="text" name="txt3" #input3>
      <input type="text" name="txt4">
      <input type="text" name="txt5">
      <input type="text" name="txt6">
    </div>
    <button (click)="selectSample()">select</button>`
})    
export class SamplesComponent {

  @ViewChild('input3') input3:ElementRef;

  constructor(private _renderer : Renderer) {}

  public selectSample() {
     //as per Eric's suggestion
     this._renderer.invokeElementMethod(this.input3.nativeElement, 'focus', []);
  }
}
```

Comment: @EricMartinez Ohh, would you look at that! I suppose you are talking about `Renderer` in combination with `invokeElementMethod`? Just looked at the documentation, never heard of `Renderer` before. Thanks for this idea. I somehow dislike the idea as well of using `nativeElement`

Comment: yes, actually accessing directly nativeElement is discouraged, see [ElementRef](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ElementRef-class.html), so the safest way is use Renderer since is webworker safe.

Comment: @EricMartinez I've updated my answer. Thanks for the explanation, it especially makes sense now when you take webworkers into consideration.

Comment: Renderer is deprecated and new [Renderer2 doesn't have invokeElementMethod](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13818#issuecomment-283417820) method.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a Directive implementation, per Eric's suggestion:

```
@Directive({selector: 'input'})
export class MyInput {
  constructor(private _elRef:ElementRef, private _renderer:Renderer) {}
  focusIf(attrValue:string) {
    console.log(this._elRef.nativeElement.getAttribute('name'))
    if(this._elRef.nativeElement.getAttribute('name') === attrValue) {
      this._renderer.invokeElementMethod(this._elRef.nativeElement, 'focus', []);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [MyInput],
  template: `<div>
      <input type="text" name="txt1">
      <input type="text" name="txt2">
      <input type="text" name="txt3">
      <input type="text" name="txt4">
      <input type="text" name="txt5">
      <input type="text" name="txt6">
    </div>
    <button (click)="selectSample()">click</button>`
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChildren(MyInput) inputs;
  constructor() { console.clear(); }
  selectSample() {
    this.inputs.toArray().some(myInput =>
      myInput.focusIf('txt3'));
  }
}
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rq50jYSeFQsliFWo7stU?p=preview)</kbd>

I like the directive approach, because we don't need to add `#input` to the HTML, and the directive knows how to focus itself.

I used `Array.some()` just to be slightly more efficient.

Comment: Renderer is deprecated and new [Renderer2 doesn't have invokeElementMethod](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13818#issuecomment-283417820) method.

Answer (score 3):

My approach would be to rely on a Directive and its selector, to remove the necessity of iterating over an array, and to avoid the local variables (I don't like the idea of having too many of them on my view), as Mark mentioned.

I'm assuming that the user always want only one and it's hardcoded, which is enough for the case the user asked about. Having a dynamic element to focus would defeat this approach.

The directive

```js
@Directive({
  selector : 'input[type=text][name=txt3]'
})
class Input {
  constructor(public renderer: Renderer, public elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  focusMe() {
    this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'focus', []);
  }
}
```

The component would be basically the same in each answer

```js
export class App {
  @ViewChild(Input) input: Input;

  selectSample() {
    this.input.focusMe();
  }
}
```

Here's the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/3wufGFN4hiJ8JrTsGKxg?p=preview).

Comment: Renderer is deprecated and new [Renderer2 doesn't have invokeElementMethod](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13818#issuecomment-283417820) method.