# PrimeNG Multiselect autofocus

Tags: angular, primeng, autofocus, primeng-dropdowns

Using PrimgNG v7.1.3 in Angular v7 project.

Implemented Multiselect (https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-7.1.3/#/multiselect), in a simple component.

Need to set focus on it when the page loads.

**Below solution works for Dropdown but not for Multiselect:**

In HTML:
`<p-dropdown #someDropdown></p-dropdown>`

In Component:

```
import { Dropdown } from 'primeng/dropdown';
@ViewChild('someDropdown') someDropdown: Dropdown;

this.someDropdown.applyFocus();
```

But for Multiselect, it throws error that such method is not valid.

Tried the first answer in this SO link mentioned for "control within ngIf", still no luck: [primeng: Setting focus on control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41042513/primeng-setting-focus-on-control)

Checked the PrimeNG documentation and User Guide too but no mention of focusing feature.

Later also tried below. None of it worked.

```
this.someMultiSelect.focus();
this.someMultiSelect.applyFocus();

this.someMultiSelect.el.focus();
this.someMultiSelect.el.applyFocus();

this.someMultiSelect.el.nativeElement.focus();
this.someMultiSelect.el.nativeElement.applyFocus();

this.someMultiSelect.containerViewChild.focus();
this.someMultiSelect.containerViewChild.applyFocus();

this.someMultiSelect.containerViewChild.nativeElement.focus();
this.someMultiSelect.containerViewChild.nativeElement.applyFocus();
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-multiselect-autofocus

Please suggest.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get element by `ViewChild` and do this trick to make it highlighted.

something like this:

**Component**

```
import { MultiSelect } from 'primeng/multiselect';

export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  name = 'Angular';

  @ViewChild('someDropdown') someDropdown: MultiSelect; // <--- you need to import this from PrimeNG Library

 ngAfterViewInit() {
   setTimeout(() => {
     this.someDropdown.containerViewChild.nativeElement.click();  
     this.someDropdown.hide();
   }, 300);

  }
```

Here is the Stackblitz example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngprime-multiselect-efpy6z?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I need to set focus and not open the multi-select. User may or may not want to open the multiselect but the focus should be set on page load itself.

Comment: @KunalDethe can you check the example one more time? Is this what you want?

Comment: I have added the Stackblitz link in the description.

Comment: To ease the testing part, added a button and on click of it should set focus on the element.

Comment: @KunalDethe yes, I saw your created example, but please can you clarify, what do you mean by saying, set focus on the element? Did you mean you want to somehow highlight the multiselect field?

Comment: Yes, it should be highlighted when User presses the keyboard "Tab" key to traverse in a form. In a HTML form, we set `tabindex` to each element's sequencing. If one of the form element is this PrimeNG dropdown or multiselect then it should also be highlighted using the `outline` CSS property. Then there is `autofocus` concept too.

Comment: Updated the Stackblitz link with proper demo for Dropdown and MultiSelect element focus behavior. Please check.

Comment: @KunalDethe Look In your example, on my side the tab press is working for both items.
but the set focus by click doesn't work. I make it work by my example. Please have a look at the example.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-multiselect-autofocus-kywbgn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218271/discussion-between-kunal-dethe-and-ashot-aleqsanyan).

Comment: please update your answer as per the solution mentioned in your latest Stackblitz link. I can then mark the answer as accepted.