# AngularJS2: How to focus input like document.getElementById(..).focus in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, focus

I'm writing a login form in AngularJS2 and I want cursor to focus username input when the user or password return false. How can I do it?

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" #inputUsername placeholder="Username" autofocus ngControl="username" [(ngModel)]="username">
<input type="password" class="form-control" #inputPassword placeholder="Password" ngControl="password" [(ngModel)]="password">

this.loginService.getAuth(username, password)
  .subscribe(auth => {
    if (auth == true) {
        ????
    } else {
        ????
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a directive like explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/34573219/217408 and modify it a bit:

```ts
@Directive({
  selector : '[focusable]'
})
class Focusable {
  constructor(public renderer: Renderer, public elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  focus() {
    this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(
      this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'focus', []);
  }
}
```

then use it like

```ts
<input focusable type="text" class="form-control" #inputUsername placeholder="Username" autofocus ngControl="username" [(ngModel)]="username">
<input type="password" class="form-control" #inputPassword placeholder="Password" ngControl="password" [(ngModel)]="password">
```

*Don't forget to add it to `directives: [Focusable]*

You can query for that directive like

```ts
@ViewChild(Focusable) focusable:Focusable;

...
if(auth == true) {
  ...
} else {
  this.focusable.focus();
}
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/aq7AES14demsV1claaFh?p=preview)

Comment: I got an error  "Cannot read property 'focus' of undefined".

This letter  `this.focusable.focus();`   is error

Comment: Are you calling `this.focusable.focus()` in the constructor? `@ViewChild()` queries are not set before `ngAfterViewInit()` is called. I added a Plunker example.

Comment: May I ask you more a question? This example has only 1 selector and fix to only 1 element. How can I make it more flexible? like 'getElementById'.

Comment: You can add a template variable to the input and query by variable name like `<input focusable #myInput>` and `@ViewChild('myInput')`. You might need to add the `read` parameter like `@ViewChild('myInput', {read: Focusable})`. You can also use `@ViewChildren(Focusable) focusables:QueryList<Focusable>` and then iterate the list `this.focusables.toArray()...`

Comment: If this fixes your issue, can you please accept the answer using the which checkmark below the up/down-vote buttons to indicate your question is answered?

Comment: Of course. I have done it but they tell me I have reputation less than 15. I will do it as fast as I can. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know that limitation.