# how to auto focus a input in a modal window

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, angular, bootstrap-modal

i'm using angular2 but this modal I did it with bootstrap3. I have the following input in the modal windows

```
<img id='searchIcon' src="images/search.png" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade modal-container" role="dialog">
     <h1>search</h1>
     <input [focus]='true' id='inputSearch' type="text">
</div>
```

and I would like when I open the modal window to have the input focused (kind of is in pluralsight.com when you click on the magnifier icon).

As you see I tried [focus]='true'but didn't work

Answer (score 1):

This will do

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    $("#inputSearch").focus();
});
```

Comment: how do I do that on angular2? because I can't use jquery in angular 2

Comment: You can use it by import jquery library in your index.html. Be aware that if you start using it everywhere instead of angular 2 approach... well... you will have spaguetti for breakfast, lunch and dinner.

Answer (score 0):

I believe all you need to do is add `autofocus` to your input tag like this.

```
<img id='searchIcon' src="images/search.png" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade modal-container" role="dialog">
   <h1>search</h1>
   <input id='inputSearch' type="text" autofocus>
</div>
```

Comment: this works, but if a close the modal and open again and it doesn't work :S, and it doesn't work on firefox

Comment: @angel I found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34573219/2318578), it looks like it might solve a similar problem, specifically the updated section of Eric's answer. It seems odd that there's not a simpler way to deal with focus...