# How can I manage focus states on an Angular 2 custom input component?

Tags: angular, focus, custom-element

I cannot find a way to manage through Angular 2 how a custom input gets its focus from a `label` (and its `for` attribute) and how to manage those states.

I'm trying to give my  the same focus-and-blur behaviour that a regular  has. Any ideas on that?

Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34522306/angular-2-focus-on-newly-added-input-element. If this is not enough please provide more information about what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't think that link tackles the same issue. What I'm trying to do is to give my <custom-input> the same focus and blur behaviour that a regular <input> has. I'll update the question so is better understandable.

Answer (score 10):

HTML have tabindex attribute, that makes any element focusable.
http://w3c.github.io/html/editing.html#the-tabindex-attribute

Then in component you can listen focus event:

```
 @HostBinding('tabindex') tabindex = 0;

 @HostListener('focus')
 focusHandler() {
   alert('focused!');
 }
```

Comment: The key to this answer is `tabindex` if the host element used for the custom control does not normally allow focus. Instead of using `@HostListener` you can add '(focus)' to the Component decorator's `host` entry.