# How to navigate/focus to the next item in Angular2?

Tags: jquery, angular

I want to focus to the next item using Arrow keys.
In keydown event handler, I use `event.currentTarget.nextSibling` to access the next item.
Is there another way to accomplish this?
In the event handler, I want to use JQuery to do this. How to do this?

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor = "let work of works" tabindex="-1" 
        (keydown.ArrowDown)="handleKeyEvent( $event, 'Arrow Down' )">
        <div class="guide-label">
            <div>{{work.cd}}</div>
            <div>{{work.name}}</div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```
export class WorkComponent {
    ...
    handleKeyEvent(event: Event): void {

        event.currentTarget.nextSibling.focus();
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a focus directive (and register it in your `NgModule`) that calls `focus()` on the host element when the input value changes to `true`:

```
@Directive({
  selector : '[myFocus]'
})
class MyFocus {
  constructor(public renderer: Renderer, public elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  @Input()
  set myFocus(value :boolean) {
    if(value) {
      this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(
          this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'focus', []);
    }
  }
}
```

Add the selector and a binding that passes `true` or `false` to the directive when it is supposed to be focused:

```
<li *ngFor = "let work of works let idx=index" tabindex="-1" 
    [myFocus]="idx == focusedIdx" (keydown.ArrowDown)="handleKeyEvent( $event, 'Arrow Down' )">
```

Update `focusedIdx` on key events:

```
       handleKeyEvent(event: Event): void {
            this.focusedIdx++;
        }
```

See also [Angular 2: Focus on newly added input element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34522306/angular-2-focus-on-newly-added-input-element)

Comment: Could I access `idx` in `handleKeyEvent` handler?

Comment: You can pass it along `(keydown.ArrowDown)="handleKeyEvent( $event, 'Arrow Down', idx )"`

Comment: When I navigate to the next `li` tag, I want to change the style of this `li` tag and the previous `li` tag.
I could use `this.elementRef.nativeElement` to handle this. In my opinion, this way is not concise.Could I use JQuery to accomplish this?

Comment: `[class.some-class]="idx == focusedIdx"` or `[ngClass]="{'some-class': idx == focusedIdx}"` or `[style.background-color]="idx == focusedIdx ? 'red' : 'green'"`