# Switch focus between fields in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, focus

I need to switch focus between fields if user press enter. And if both fields(login & pwd) are not empty $scope.submit Is called. The question is how can I switch focus between this two fields? I can do it using `document.getElementByid`, but If there is no id attr? How can I get in angularjs html tag with ng-model to set focus?

JS:

```
app.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $location, $rootScope,$http){
$scope.username = '';
$scope.password = '';
$scope.enter=function(){
    if ($scope.username!="" && ($scope.password=="" || $scope.password==undefined)) document.getElementById("password").focus();
    else if($scope.password!="" && ($scope.username=="" || $scope.username==undefined)) document.getElementById("username").focus();
    else if($scope.password!="" && $scope.username!="") $scope.submit();
};
$scope.submit=function(){
    var data={};
    data.login=$scope.username;
    data.pwd=$scope.password;
    $http.post("authorization.php", data).then(function success (response) {
        console.log(response);
        if (response.data['loggin'] === true) {
            $rootScope.loggedIn = true;
            $location.path('/dashboard');
            $rootScope.name = response.data['name'];
        }
        else {
            $scope.username = '';
            $scope.password = '';
        }
    },function error (response){
        console.log(response);
    }
    );

}
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="loginCtrl"  class="login">
    <form action="/" id="myLogin" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" ng-model="username" placeholder="Username" required="required" class="input-txt" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 ? enter() : null"><br>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" ng-model="password" placeholder="Password" required="required" class="input-txt" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 ? enter() : null"><br>
        <br>
        <button type="button" ng-click="submit()"  class="btn btn--right">Login</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: @Fran The question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41283650/how-can-i-move-focus-to-next-control-on-key-enter-in-angular-2 is regarding Angular/Angular4, this question is related to Angular 1.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this will help you out.Thank you.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" ng-model="username" placeholder="Username" required="required" class="input-txt" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 ? enter() : null" focus-me="setFocusValueName"><br>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" ng-model="password" placeholder="Password" required="required" class="input-txt" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 ? enter() : null" focus-me="setFocusValuePwd"><br>
```

**Directive**

```
  directive('focusMe', function () {
      return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          scope.$watch(attrs.focusMe, function (value) {
            if (value === true) {
              console.log('value=', value);
              element[0].focus();
              scope[attrs.focusMe] = false;
            }
          });
        }
      };
    });
```

**Controller**

In controller set TRUE/FALSE for $scope.setFocusValueName & $scope.setFocusValuePwd based on your requirement.

$scope.setFocusValueName = true/false;
$scope.setFocusValuePwd = true/false;