# How to traverse dom in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, html, angular, dom

I am using Angular 5 for one of my projects. In one of my component, I have an HTML table, in which I have `input` fields.

Now I need keyboard shortcuts for this input fields, for example, if a user press `enter` key, the next input field should be focused. Same way if a user press `backspace` key just previous field should be focused.

This type of operation I have done earlier in `jQuery`, using `$(this).next('input').focus();` and `$(this).prev('input').focus();`.

Now how can I do the same thing in Angular 5?

Also, In some case, I have nested table and input fields inside this nested tables. I need the same behavior on that input fields (just `.next()` and `.prev()` is not enough, we need to find the next input field form the DOM).

How can I achieve this? Please help.

**EDIT**

What I have tried so far

```
<input id="first_element_{{i}}" type="text" class="form-control" #particular [required]="transaction.amount" [(ngModel)]="transaction.selectedAccount.account" (keyup)="searchAccount($event?.target?.value);" (focus)="onAccountFocus(transaction.type === 'A' ? amountField1 : amountField2, transaction.type, i);" (blur)="onAccountBlur($event);" [ngClass]="{'focus': isSelectedRow && selectedIdx === i}" (keydown)="detectKey($event)" (keydown.Tab)="validateAccount(transaction, $event, i)">
```

I have added `(blur)`, `(keydown)` and `(keydown.Tab)` to achieve this but at the end I am not able to find the exact `next` and `prev` elements from the dom.

Comment: Why is a solution like this not enough? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41283650/move-focus-to-next-control-on-key-enter

Comment: What about using a directive?

Comment: `Now how can I do the same thing in Angular 5?` What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/41311816/5369031 this answer, but in `e.srcElement.nextElementSibling` I am getting `table` element instead of `input` fields inside `table > tbody > tr > td`.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with '@ViewChildren('name')' inputs : QueryList and putting '#name' on your focusable inputs. 
This will give you a queryList of ElementRef witch could be focusable (element.nativeElement.focus()).
For me you should work with a HostListening like '@HostListener('window:keyup', ['$event'])' to trigger each keys event, so inside you could get your input list, the input where the event is trigger ($event). It just still to put the focusable logic inside!
I hope it's help you !