# Programmatically focus and select angular2 material design input

Tags: angular, focus, angular-material

Using angular2 and angular2-material with following pattern:

```
<form #userForm="ngForm" style="background-color: rgba(209,216,239,0.29)" layout-padding="20px">
        <div layout="row" layout-margin>
          <md-input-container flex>
            <input md-input
                   #eAccountName
                   #cAccountName="ngModel"
                   type="text"
                   placeholder="Account Name"
                   [(ngModel)]="accountName"
                   name="accountname"
                   maxlength="50"
                   [disabled]="!isEditable"
                   required>
          </md-input-container>
        </div>
</form>
```

How do I programmatically focus this (or any other) input element?  If possible, I'd also like to select the contents of the text field once its focused.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34522306/angular-2-focus-on-newly-added-input-element

Comment: Gunter - thank you, but no.  Similar code that I've tried does not work in my case.  It might have something to do with angular2-material.  I'm looking for a solution that works with that framework.

Comment: I don't see why it would be different

Comment: - - Neither do I.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the focus method from the md-input component as shown in the documentation

https://material.angular.io/components/input/api

```html
<span (click)="myinput.focus()">Focus it!</span>
<md-input-container class="example-full-width">
    <input mdInput #myinput>
</md-input-container>
```

To focus from inside a class:

```js
export class AppComponent {
    @ViewChild('myinput') articleInput;
    someMethod() {
        this.articleInput.nativeElement.focus();
    }
}
```

Update from comments, thanks to khoailang

You can use a timeout to set focus after a short period of time, to be sure the view is initialized, and autofocus the desired input

```js
export class MyDemoComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    interval: Subscription;
    @ViewChild('viewInputName') input;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.interval = Observable.interval(750).subscribe(x => {
            this.input.nativeElement.focus();
            this.interval.unsubscribe();
        });
    }
}
```

Always remember to unsubscribe from the interval.

Comment: can you provide a plunker please

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know how to create a project like angular in plunker.

If my example does not work keep in mind that when I wrote it I was using angular 4.

Comment: thank you, I figured out my issue, I get it works by put the focus() inside a setTimeout()

Comment: @khoailang Its better to use subscriptions, and do not forget to unsubscribe