# Handle Tab event

Tags: angular

How can I handle a <kbd>Tab</kbd> `keypress` event in Angular 2?

I took this from the Angular docs to get the `keyCode`. It works well when I press the other keys, but when I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> nothing happens.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'my-app',
 template: `<input (keyup)="onKey($event)">
            <p>{{values}}</p>`
})

export class AppComponent {
  values = '';
  onKey(event: any) { 
  this.values += event.keyCode+ ' | ';
  }
}
```

Also, is this the correct way to do it in Angular 2?

```
<input ng-keydown="($event.keyCode == 9) && 
       signal('something')" />
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

```
 <input (keydown.Tab)="onKey($event)">
```

Comment: You need to add `tabundex="0"` so the div can receive the focus and keyboard events.

Comment: Thank you a lot! that works for me. Is there a way to prevent the default events of Tab. event.preventDefault() ?

Comment: I don't really understsnd the comment but `preventDefault()` is called when `false` is returned like `<input (keydown.Tab)="onKey($event);false">`. Alternatively `onKey()` can retzrn `false` or call `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: When I press Tab, at first the focus is on the whole browser window then the browser tab then the page and then the div and finally it executes what should be done on the div. I want to ignore all this and execute my onKey fuction when I press Tab for the first time.

Comment: You need to ensure that the element has the focus from the beginning, then `onKey()` should executed on the first `tab` press. You set the focus by calling `element.focus()`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/34573219/217408 shows a directive that does that (using the `Renderer`)

Comment: Would you say that the syntax of `(eventname.SpecificThing)=foo()` is a hacky work-around for special cases when the required effect can't be achieved in other ways (a sort of last resource to make stuff work)? Or should we consider using it when e.g. the only event that needs handling is pressing a certain key, like `(keyup.X)=reactToX()` (in a weird scenario where we only do stuff when the user types "x")?

Comment: @KonradViltersten only the later

Answer (score 4):

```
<input (keypress)="someFunction($event.target.value)"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

I was having a similar problem. I initially tried using `$event` in the template, but after some reading [here](https://angular.io/guide/user-input#passing-event-is-a-dubious-practice), it seems passing `$event` isn't something the Angular team encourages (see the link for detail). They recommend using template reference variables. This was fine until I tried using tab and I ended up getting what @freeNinja was getting; tab would work but then direct focus to the top of the page. @ Günter Zöchbauer answer in the comments above worked for me. Adding false after the method call stopped the focus from being transferred.
`(keydown.tab)="saveEntry(i, newCost.value); false`