# Angular mat-menu close on click tab event

Tags: angular, angular-material, focus

I am using mat-menu to display a form and need to change focus between inputs on the tab keypress event. But when I press tab, the mat-menu closes.

Example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u5qbkt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42240486/handle-tab-event

Comment: i have update your stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zwxjiw

Comment: @TheBallkar Please check this link. it  help you https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hyfu7r?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 6):

In form tag write this line `(keydown.tab)="$event.stopPropagation()"`

like this->

```
 <form (keydown.tab)="$event.stopPropagation()" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()" (click)="stop($event)" class="formValueGenerator" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: Also you can add `(keydown.shift.tab)="$event.stopPropagation()"` for shift tab