# Change focus to a form filed in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I am creating a `crud application` in `angular`. I want the username to be unique and want to `throw an error` if the username is not unique and then place the `cursor` at the username field. I am able to `throw the error` and notify the user but I'm unable to change the `focus` to the username field.

Thanks in advance for the help.

**Below is my typeScript code:**

```
export class AdduserComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private userService: UsersService,
    private router: Router,
    private snackBar: MatSnackBar
  ) { }

  addForm: FormGroup;
  passwordsMatcher = new RepeatPasswordEStateMatcher;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.addForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      id: [],
      userName: ['', Validators.required],
      password: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      passwordAgain: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      userRole: ['', Validators.required],

    }, { validator: RepeatPasswordValidator });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    if (this.addForm.valid) {
      this.userService.createUser(this.addForm.value)
        .subscribe(data => {
          console.log(data);
          this.snackBar.open("New User Created", "Success", {
            duration: 1000,
          });
          setTimeout(
            function () {
              window.location.reload();
            }, 2000);
          //this.router.navigate(['adduser']);
        }, error => {
            console.log(error);
            this.snackBar.open("Username Already Exists", "Please Provide Different UserName", {
              duration: 2000,
            });
            this.addForm.controls.userName.reset();
          });
    }
    //window.location.reload();
  }

  changeClient(value) { }

  resetForm() {
    console.log("Reset called");
    this.addForm.reset();
  }

}
```

**Below is the html code:**

```
<div  style="height: 100vh" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center" >
  <mat-toolbar class="toolbar">
    <span class="span">Create New NI User</span>
  </mat-toolbar>
    <mat-card class="card">
        <mat-card-content>

    <form [formGroup]="addForm" class="login-form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
          <mat-icon matSuffix  > person_identity</mat-icon>
      <input matInput type="text" formControlName="userName" placeholder="UserName" name="userName" class="form-control" id="userName">
      <mat-error *ngIf="addForm.controls.userName.hasError('required')" >UserName can't be empty</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <p></p>
    <div class="form-group"> 
        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">

      <input matInput [type]="!hide ? 'password' : 'text'" formControlName="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" class="form-control" id="password">
      <mat-icon matSuffix (click)="hide = !hide">{{hide ? 'visibility' : 'visibility_off'}}</mat-icon>

      <mat-error *ngIf="addForm.controls.password.hasError('required')" >Passwords can't be empty</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <p></p>

    <div class="form-field">
        <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput formControlName="passwordAgain" placeholder="Confirm password" [type]="!hides ? 'password' : 'text'" [errorStateMatcher]="passwordsMatcher">
        <mat-icon matSuffix (click)="hides = !hides">{{hides ? 'visibility' : 'visibility_off'}}</mat-icon>

        <mat-error *ngIf="addForm.hasError('passwordsNotEqual')" >Passwords are different. They should be equal!</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <p></p>

    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-icon matSuffix>accessibility</mat-icon>

        <mat-select placeholder="User Role"  formControlName="userRole" id="userRole" (selectionChange)="changeClient($event.value)" >
          <mat-option value="Admin">Admin</mat-option>


        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>

      <div class="container" style="margin: 12px" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">


    <button mat-raised-button class="bt" color="primary">Create</button>
    <button mat-raised-button type="reset"  (click)= "resetForm()" color="warn">Cancel</button>


      </div>
  </form>



  </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
</div>
```

Comment: Add the related HTML Code

Comment: Add a "reference" to the html field using the `#`. Then, in your component, add a `ViewChild` pointing to it, then use `.nativeElement.focus()` on it to trigger the focus.

Comment: @PrashantPimpale added the html code.

Comment: @briosheje can you give an example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 5 set focus on input element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50006888/angular-5-set-focus-on-input-element)

Comment: @rock11 check the duplicate I related, you're likely trying to do the same thing ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the `focus()` method of the `HTMLInputElement`. To do that, place a reference on your input, for example `#username`, and then read it in your code with `ViewChild('username')`:

```
<input #username matInput type="text" formControlName="userName" ...>
```

```
import { ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
...
@ViewChild('username') usernameRef: ElementRef;
...
usernameRef.nativeElement.focus();
```