# Losing the focus on an input that appears conditionally - Angular 7

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-material

I have a cell inside a table that I'm allowing the user to edit the text inside the cell, when the user choosing 
to edit the text a material input that contains the text as a value appears (the input appers VIA a `*ngIf` condition ).
I want that a cursor will blink inside that input, but it's blinking only at the first time that the input element is appears.

```
 <div *ngIf="showInput === row._id">
      <input autofocus matInput type="text" [value]="row.name" />
 </div>
```

There is a similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833326/how-to-set-focus-on-input-field) like my that already been answered, but unfortunately it refers to angularJS

Comment: This is the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50006888/set-focus-on-input-element