# Angular - Unable to get operation to work in both ways

Tags: angular

I'm using @HostListener("document:keyup", ["$event"]) to have a real Time operation. 
Let's say I have 3 inputs: A B and R(result). I want to sum A+B and show R in its input. 
But I'd like to modify R and get B modified by R-A.

On screen:

Input A: 5

Input B: 3

Input R: 8

Then, modify R manually to 5 change the value of B.

Input R: 8 -> 5.
Input B should turn 0. But it never turns 0 because as soon as I press anything the function just calculates A+B and gives the result on R. 
How can I achieve this without creating a loop?

```
 @HostListener("document:keyup", ["$event"])
  public operar(){

    this.gananciaEuros = 0;
    this.gananciaPorcentaje ="";
    this.resultado = "";
    this.calc.controls.total.setValue(0);
    if (!this.calc.controls.costo.value || !this.calc.controls.precioNeto.value) { //si la var está vacía
      this.calc.controls.total.setValue("Rellene ambos campos");
    }else{
      this.resultado = Number(Number(this.calc.controls.precioNeto.value) / Number(this.calc.controls.costo.value));
      this.gananciaEuros = Number((Number(this.calc.controls.precioNeto.value) - Number(this.calc.controls.costo.value)).toFixed(2));
      this.gananciaPorcentaje = String(((this.resultado - 1) * 100).toFixed(2));
      this.calc.controls.total.setValue(Number(this.gananciaEuros)/* +" (" + String(this.gananciaPorcentaje) +"%)" */);
      this.calc.controls.precioNeto.setValue(Number(this.gananciaEuros) + Number(this.calc.controls.costo.value))
    }
  }
```

html

```
<div class="divformulario">
    <form [formGroup]="calc">
        <div class="formsubconjuntovertical spacebetween">
         <div [innerHtml]="'Calcular Ganancia sobre precio' | uppercase | bold" "></div>
            <mat-form-field>
                <mat-label>Precio costo</mat-label>
                <input matInput type="number" formControlName="costo" />
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field  >
                <mat-label>Precio de venta neto</mat-label>
                <input matInput type="number" formControlName="precioNeto" " />
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field>
                <mat-label>Ganancia</mat-label>
                <input matInput type="number" formControlName="total" style="text-align: right;" "/><span matSuffix>€</span>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Post your code please. It is impossible for us to guess what is going wrong without seeing the function

Comment: Code added for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using an `HostListener`, you can use the event `keyup` and bind the three values (a, b, r) to component variables.

Here is an exemple of the `html` file:

```
A
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="aValue" (keyup)="changeFromA($event)"/>

B
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="bValue" (keyup)="changeFromB($event)"/>

R
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="rValue" (keyup)="changeFromR($event)"/>
```

And in you component:

```
aValue : number = 5;
bValue : number = 3;
rValue : number = 8;

changeFromA(_ : any) {
  this.rValue = this.aValue + this.bValue;
}

changeFromB(_ : any) {
  this.rValue = this.aValue + this.bValue;
}

changeFromR(_ : any) {
  this.bValue = this.rValue - this.aValue;
}
```

Comment: I'll try this way. Meanwhile, as I'm very new with Angular, what is this underscore that you put in the parenthesis of each function? I understand that ": any" is the type of the variable that typescript needs, but I don't know what a underscore means.

Comment: It's just the `$event` parameter, I could have written `changeFromA(event : KeyboardEvent)`. I called this parameter `_` because I know I won't use it in my function. That's just a name. :)

Comment: I have tried with a little test - it works probably as expected by  "keyup"- however, the inputs contains little arrows up and down to modify the number by clicking them (1 up, 1 down). When I use these little buttons, the result is not changed, probably because they are not "keyup". Any suggestion? (Edit: I'm doing it without   passing $event)

Comment: Add on each input `(change)="changeFromX($event)"` so it will also detect this change.

Comment: That works wonderfully.  Thanks a lot, Powkachu. (Nice nick btw). May I ask you one last thing? I have been trying to find a easy way to move the focus to the next input on enter key press. However, every way I have found on the internet are long implementations of code that I quite don't understand. I wonder if you (that seem to know well Angular) know a way to make this focus change easily. I hope you don't mind to help me with this extra question. Thank you.

Comment: Haha happy to help! [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50006888/5049472) can help, it's what I'm used to use. You need to use `@ViewChild` and `myElement.nativeElement.focus()`.