# JavaScript .focus() function not working in a text field

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to use .focus() on the following form field without success. The `tabindex` of the div this element is in is 0.

```
<input class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched" id="accessionNumber" type="text" name="filter.accessionNumber" ng-model="selectFields.accessionNumber" style="">
```

I'm using the following:

```
document.getElementsByName("filter.accessionNumber")[0].focus()
```

I've also tried `document.getElementById` using the "accessionNumber" ID as well as the `.click()` function instead of the `.focus()` function but none have worked so far

Thanks!

Comment: You should add Angular tag to your question, it might be the reason for your problem. BTW Angular is no longer supported so if you are able to abandon ship, do so soon.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Maybe have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50006888/set-focus-on-input-element)

Longer answer: Since you are using Angular you should use the features of the framework that enable this: [ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild)

Steps to make it work:

1. In your component create a variable with the ViewChild annotation
2. Mark the element with the ViewChild id in the Components Template
3. Access your element in `ngAfterViewInit`like

```
this.myElement.nativeElement.focus();
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying to interact with the form via a userscript in Tampermonkey--is it possible to achieve this using plain JavaScript?

Comment: In that case i think you can go with `querySelector`like:

`document.querySelector("#accessionNumber").focus()`