# How do I change the body class via a typescript class (angular2)

Tags: styles, angular

How do I change the body class via the root component?

```ts
@Component({ 
   selector: "app", 
   directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES], 
   template: ` 
       <section class="header"> 
           <h1>App</h1>  
           <router-outlet></router-outlet> ` 
})
```

Comment: You want to add/remove a CSS class to the `<body>` tag?

Comment: yes, when a user checked a checkbox I want to change my style of the page. So I want to change the class of the body tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2.x bind class on body tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34430666/angular-2-x-bind-class-on-body-tag)

Answer (score 23):

Here you can simple use the native JavaScript in the Angular2 component to change the class of the `<body>` tag:-

```
let body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
body.classList.remove("className");   //remove the class
body.classList.add("className");   //add the class
```

Comment: Still in Angular2 it's not working  we will have a separate style class added

Comment: This is not really an angular answer

Comment: Angular does still work with plain old JavaScript and DOM access. This may not be the most "Angular" way to do it, but it does work, and works just fine.

Answer (score 22):

One way that doesn't depend on direct DOM manipulation is, to make the `<body>` tag the app element by using `body` as selector and use host-binding to update the app elements classes.

```ts
@Component({
   selector: 'body',
   host:     {'[class.someClass]':'someField'}
})
export class AppElement implements AfterViewInit {
  someField: bool = false;
  // alternatively to the host parameter in `@Component`
  // @HostBinding('class.someClass') someField: bool = false;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    someField = true; // set class `someClass` on `<body>`
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it also possible to toggle the someField value from a function on runtime?

Comment: @FerdiEmmen that's how it's supposed to be used.

Comment: Ok, how can I toggle the class with a button then?

Comment: `template: '<button (click)="someField = !someField">toggle</button>'`

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I guess I was not clear enough. I created a plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/ra8uK5MoYyenhAPYHpLY?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the plunker but it's still unclear what you try to accomplish. What do you expect the `Body` component to do? Just adding it as `providers` to `Toggle`, the component you bootstrap Angular with, doesn't do anything. You also can only attach the root component to the body tag.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107209/discussion-between-ferdi-emmen-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer where to add @Component with `body` selector?

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya It has to be the root component (`AppComponent`). There is no way to do this on any other component.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I have `selector: 'app-root'`, If I change to `body` will it work?

Comment: Yes. You should be aware that all `<body>` tag content will be purged when your `AppComponent` gets initialised. So if you have script tags or other content inside `<body>`, you need to move these somewhere else or use another approach to set the class on `<body>`.

Answer (score 6):

Use below code.

```js
 ngOnInit() {
    let body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    body.classList.add('body-landing');
  }
  
  
  ngOnDestroy() {
    let body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    body.classList.remove("body-landing");
  }
```

Comment: aleady same answer available plz avoid duplicates

Comment: I thought accessing directly element attributes was discouraged?

Answer (score 4):

Still looking for a better solution, here is my current workaround:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
    selector: 'signup',
    templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./signup.component.css',], // Where my custom CSS styles for body element declared
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None, // That will not encapsulate my CSS styles (layout-full, page-signup) from signup.component.css inside component
})


export class SignupComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy{

    bodyClasses:string = "layout-full page-signup";

    ngOnInit(): void {
        $('body').addClass(this.bodyClasses);
    }
    ngOnDestroy() { 
        $('body').removeClass(this.bodyClasses);
    }


}
```

Comment: if that's jquery a better solution would be just to use any other answer, no point including the whole library

Answer (score 3):

In case someone needs to add and remove class from body only when a specific component is active, it can be done as below. In my specific case, I wanted to add the "**landing-page**" class only when user lands on Home Page (View) and remove that class when user navigates to other views:

```
import {Component, OnInit, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() {}

    //Add the class to body tag when the View is initialized
    ngOnInit() {
        let body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        body.classList.add("landing-page");
    }

    //Remove the class from body tag when the View is destroyed
    ngOnDestroy() {
        let body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        body.classList.remove("landing-page");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

i resove it by use the routeing - like this
-add to the root-app component this code :

```
 this.activeRouter.events.subscribe(
      data => {
        this.className = data.url.split('/').join(' ').trim();
        this.changeBodyClass();
      })
```

and the body change:

```
changeBodyClass(){
    if(this.el.nativeElement.parentElement.nodeName === 'BODY'){
       this.el.nativeElement.parentElement.className = this.className ? this.className + '-page' : 'home-page';
    }
```

you need to inject in the constractor:

```
constructor(private activeRouter: Router,
              private el: ElementRef)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 ngOnInit() {
         let body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
         body.classList.add('nom_class');                                           
 }
```

For add one or more classes to the element:

```
body.classList.add('make', 'me', 'look', 'rad');
```