# @HostBinding and @HostListener: what do they do and what are they for?

Tags: angular, angular-services

In my meanderings around the world wide interweb, and now especially the [angular.io style docs](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide), I find many references to `@HostBinding` and `@HostListener`. It seems they are quite fundamental, but unfortunately the documentation for them at the moment is a little sketchy.

Can anyone please explain what they are, how they work and give an example of their usage?

Answer (score 182, accepted):

Have you checked these official docs?

[HostListener](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/HostListener-interface.html) - Declares a host listener. Angular will invoke the decorated method when the host element emits the specified event.

**`@HostListener`** - will listen to the event emitted by the host element that's declared with `@HostListener`.

[HostBinding](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/HostBinding-interface.html) - Declares a host property binding. Angular automatically checks host property bindings during change detection. If a binding changes, it will update the host element of the directive.

**`@HostBinding`** - will bind the property to the host element, If a binding changes, `HostBinding` will update the host element.

---

**NOTE:** Both links have been removed recently. The "[HostBinding-HostListening](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/style-guide.html)" portion of the style guide may be a useful alternative until the links return.

---

Here's a simple code example to help picture what this means:

**DEMO : Here's the demo live in plunker - ["A simple example about @HostListener & @HostBinding"](https://plnkr.co/edit/mgiqrDsdAO1nZz7nwo4X?p=info)**

- This example binds a `role` property -- declared with `@HostBinding` -- to the host's element

  - Recall that `role` is an attribute, since we're using `attr.role`.
  - `<p myDir>` becomes `<p mydir="" role="admin">` when you view it in developer tools.
- It then listens to the `onClick` event declared with `@HostListener`, attached to the component's host element, changing `role` with each click.

  - The change when the `<p myDir>` is clicked is that its opening tag changes from `<p mydir="" role="admin">` to `<p mydir="" role="guest">` and back.

**directives.ts**

```ts
import {Component,HostListener,Directive,HostBinding,Input} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({selector: '[myDir]'})
export class HostDirective {
    @HostBinding('attr.role') role = 'admin';
    @HostListener('click') onClick() {
        this.role= this.role === 'admin' ? 'guest' : 'admin';
    }
}
```

**AppComponent.ts**

```ts
import { Component,ElementRef,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {HostDirective} from './directives';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template:
        `
        <p myDir>
            Host Element 
            <br><br>
        
            We have a (HostListener) listening to this host's 
            <b>click event</b> declared with @HostListener
        
            <br><br>
        
            And we have a (HostBinding) binding <b>the role property</b>
            to host element declared with @HostBinding 
            and checking host's property binding updates.
            
            If any property change is found I will update it.
        </p>
        
        <div>
            View this change in the DOM of the host element 
            by opening developer tools, clicking the host element in the UI. 
        
            The role attribute's changes will be visible in the DOM.
        </div> 
        `,
    directives: [HostDirective]
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

Comment: are this decorator still used it seems the links have been removed from angular2 documentation

Comment: Yes, it is still in use but let me confirm it once. I 'll update you,  if I can figure out something else.

Comment: They are on the cheat sheet: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/cheatsheet.html

Comment: @Mr.EasyAnswersMcFly updated answer with note and link. Please note still proper documentation is not available.

Comment: @micronyks For what you just said in the answer. Where can I find document for it? Thanks!

Comment: Guys, Performance question.. If I used `@HostListener` with the window scroll event inside of a directive and there were multiple instances of that directive will the event listener be binded to all of the instances or it will only have one listener and run the methods inside of it ?

Comment: @MuhammadSaleh please show it practically its hard to guess and answer.

Comment: @micronyks Please check this [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/DWwRFI07GNc95IbwyvYd?p=preview)
Check it's console please
In this example I have multiple instances of the same directive
So my question is: does this mean that I will have multiple number of event listeners listening to the scroll event [bad performance I suppose] or Angular is smart enough to have one global window scroll event listener and just execute the methods inside, or it doesn't make a big difference ?

Comment: @MuhammadSaleh for scroll its hard to say that how it counts and calculates...but that is for sure that each instance will have a separate listener

Comment: If anyone is looking for an example I found this a quick read and at the bottom you can cut and paste and play with the code - https://ng2.codecraft.tv/custom-directives/hostlistener-and-hostbinding/

Comment: I don't think there is a `directives` attribute for `@Component`

Comment: More information about @HostBinding you can find https://indepth.dev/posts/1429/making-hostbinding-work-with-observables

Answer (score 255):

A quick tip that helps me remember what they do -

`HostBinding('value') myValue;` is exactly the same as `[value]="myValue"`

And

`HostListener('click') myClick(){ }` is exactly the same as `(click)="myClick()"`

---

`HostBinding` and `HostListener` are written in directives 
and the other ones `(...)` and `[..]` are written inside templates (of components).

Comment: Ah, it clicked (pun intended) with me thanks to this answer. `@HostListener` is the way to go when you don't have anything on the DOM for typical event binding, such as keyboard input in my case.

Answer (score 58):

Here is a basic hover example.

Component's template property:

**Template**

```html
<!-- attention, we have the c_highlight class -->
<!-- c_highlight is the selector property value of the directive -->

<p class="c_highlight">
    Some text.
</p>
```

**And our directive**

```js
import {Component,HostListener,Directive,HostBinding} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    // this directive will work only if the DOM el has the c_highlight class
    selector: '.c_highlight'
 })
export class HostDirective {

  // we could pass lots of thing to the HostBinding function. 
  // like class.valid or attr.required etc.

  @HostBinding('style.backgroundColor') c_colorrr = "red"; 

  @HostListener('mouseenter') c_onEnterrr() {
   this.c_colorrr= "blue" ;
  }

  @HostListener('mouseleave') c_onLeaveee() {
   this.c_colorrr = "yellow" ;
  } 
}
```

Comment: I do not see this accepted answer as an answer to the question asked. Would you care to provide some explanation? Like what c_colorrr, c_onEnterrr(), c_onLeaveeee do in this particular code snippet?

Comment: I thik it should change colour on mouse enter event to blue and on mouse leave event to yellow.

Comment: Where do you place the directive in the markup? Seems you would place it on the body tag, but that would be outside the root component.  If you're confused by the this answer this link might help https://ng2.codecraft.tv/custom-directives/hostlistener-and-hostbinding/

Comment: @mtpultz It is in the class.

Comment: So is it only for directives??

Answer (score 39):

Another nice thing about `@HostBinding` is that you can combine it with `@Input` if your binding relies directly on an input, eg:

```
@HostBinding('class.fixed-thing')
@Input()
fixed: boolean;
```

Comment: Can you please share example on usage with `@Input()`?

Comment: The example is right there in my answer, you simply write both decorators one after the other, order should be irrelevant

Comment: I think what I am missing is how this differs from just use `@HostBinding`. When do you need to use `@Input`?

Comment: @1252748, see https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs.

Answer (score 26):

### Summary:

- `@HostBinding`: This decorator binds a **class property** to a property of the host element.
- `@HostListener`: This decorator binds a **class method** to an event of the host element.

### Example:

```
import { Component, HostListener, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<p>This is nice text<p>`,
})
export class AppComponent  {

  @HostBinding('style.color') color; 

  @HostListener('click')
  onclick() {
    this.color =  'blue';
  }

}
```

In the above example the following occurs:

- An event listener is added to the click event which will be fired when a click event occurs anywhere within the component
- The `color` property in our `AppComponent` class is bound to the `style.color` property on the component. So whenever the `color` property is updated so will the `style.color` property of our component
- The result will be that whenever someone clicks on the component the color will be updated.

### Usage in `@Directive`:

Although it can be used on component these decorators are often used in a attribute directives. When used in an `@Directive` the host changes the element on which the directive is placed. For example take a look at this component template:

```
<p p_Dir>some paragraph</p>
```

Here p_Dir is a directive on the `<p>` element. When `@HostBinding` or `@HostListener` is used within the directive class the host will now refer to the `<p>`.

Answer (score 16):

One thing that adds confusion to this subject is the idea of decorators is not made very clear, and when we consider something like...

```
@HostBinding('attr.something') 
get something() { 
    return this.somethingElse; 
 }
```

It works, because it is a [`get` accessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827266/get-and-set-in-typescript). You couldn't use a function equivalent:

```
@HostBinding('attr.something') 
something() { 
    return this.somethingElse; 
 }
```

Otherwise, the benefit of using `@HostBinding` is it assures change detection is run when the bound value changes.

Answer (score 12):

```
// begginers
@Component({
  selector: 'custom-comp',
  template: ` <div class="my-class" (click)="onClick()">CLICK ME</div> `,
})
export class CustomComp {
  onClick = () => console.log('click event');
}

// pros
@Component({
  selector: 'custom-comp',
  template: ` CLICK ME `,
})
export class CustomComp {
  @HostBinding('class.my-class') className = true;
  @HostListener('click') onClick = () => this.className = false;
}

// experts
@Component({
  selector: 'custom-comp',
  template: ` CLICK ME `,
  host: {
    class: 'my-class',
    '(click)': 'onClick()',
  },
})
export class CustomComp {
  onClick = () => console.log('click event');
}
```

**The 1st way will result in:**

```html
<custom-comp>
   <div class="my-class" (click)="onClick()">
      CLICK ME
   <div>
</custom-comp>
```

**The 2nd and 3rd ways will result in:**

```html
<custom-comp class="my-class" (click)="onClick()">
   CLICK ME
</custom-comp>
```

*NOTE: did you find the easter egg on the 2nd?*

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.

Answer (score 6):

### **Theory with less Jargons**

@Hostlistnening deals basically with the host element say (a button) listening to an action by a user and performing a certain function say alert("Ahoy!") while @Hostbinding is the other way round. Here we listen to the changes that occurred on that button internally (Say when it was clicked what happened to the class) and we use that change to do something else, say emit a particular color.

### **Example**

Think of the scenario that you would like to make a favorite icon on a component, now you know that you would have to know whether the item has been Favorited  with its class changed,  we need a way to determine this. That is exactly where @Hostbinding comes in.

And where there is the need to know what action actually was performed by the user that is where @Hostlistening comes in

Comment: This is confusing, and the decorators names are inaccurate.

Answer (score 5):

METHOD DECORATORS:

@HostBinding: Dynamic binding custom logic to Host element

```
 @HostBinding('class.active')
 activeClass = false;
```

@HostListen: To Listen to events on Host element

```
@HostListener('click')
 activeFunction(){
    this.activeClass = !this.activeClass;
 }
```

Host Element:

```
  <button type='button' class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" appHost>Host</button>
```