# Angular - extracting the click info of an HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am using Angular 4 to build an app after taking an Udemy course. I am getting started by playing around with some events. So far there is only one component app.component.ts. In my HTML, I have this header element to which I have attached a click event:

```
<h2 class="url-link" (click)="viewTopics()" #headerLink>View archived topics</h2>
```

I added the local reference #headerLink to the h2 element to try and listen to the click event in other HTML elements. But I can't do so. I did a console.log of the element in the event function:

```
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('headerLink') headerLink: ElementRef;

  viewTopics() {
    console.log(this.headerLink);
  }
}
```

The console log shows the h2 element having a property nativeElement which has the property onclick but this onclick property is always null. Is it possible to access the click event on the h2 element this way or do I have to use only (click) events on the h2 element?

Comment: You can pass "headerLink" to any function you write on the HTML. (click)="viewTopics(headerLink)" - even on another element

Comment: My question is how do I get the click info from this local reference headerLink? The only property I can find is the onclick property which is always null. Am I looking at the wrong property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<h2 (click)="viewTopics()"></h2>
<p *ngIf='headerIsClicked === true'>Toggle me</p>
<h3 *ngIf='headerIsClicked === true'>and me</h3>

viewTopics(): void {
    this.headerIsClicked = !this.headerIsClicked;
  }
```

where `headerIsClicked` is a `public` `boolean` prop for example `public headerIsClicked: boolean = false;`

Comment: My question was if I want to listen to this click event on h2 on another HTML element say a <p></p> or an <img> how would I do so? So, these other elements should display only if h2 is clicked for example. Also, the console.log(this.headerLink) in above example does not seem to have the onclick property which is still null.

Comment: you bind the click as i mentioned, then you set a state (boolean) in the viewTopics  function for example and then use *ngIf on the other elements you mentioned to hide them or make them visible

Comment: So use another variable to set the status as h2 being clicked. I managed to do that but I thought it might be possible to do it without another variable but merely check for the HTML property of h2 to listen to the click in other HTML elements.

Comment: something else but not exactly what you are asking is 
`host: {
    '(document:click)': 'onClick($event)',
  },` you might need it in the future

Comment: I found this other question on host binding and host listeners https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37965647/hostbinding-and-hostlistener-what-do-they-do-and-what-are-they-for

Answer (score 1):

You can get the click event details by passing in the event

```
<h2 class="url-link" (click)="viewTopics($event)" #headerLink>View archived topics</h2>

viewTopics(event){
    console.log('evt', event);
}
```