# What is the meaning of "CSS event"?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

When I read [the Angular docs](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener#eventName), I see these words:

> Binds a CSS event to a host listener and supplies configuration metadata

It confused me, since it is not frequently heard about "CSS event", even though I searched for a while. What does CSS event mean, and where does it come from originally?

Comment: you need to trigger an event from your template which you can bind it to  `@HostListener`, that is event likes `click` in your template

Comment: https://medium.com/@elad/css-events-3ff71bdc3b32

Comment: @Avinash trigger an event from your template, nice explanations thanks

Comment: @Paulie_D it is the only article i searched too

Comment: read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37973376/2585074)