# Anchor using Angular (Router)

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing

I am trying to work with anchors using angular i have done my research but no success so i am reaching out to you guys.

I have 3 components {NavbarComponent, RedComponent, BlueComponent} the NavbarComponent has 2 anchors. I want when i click on one of them it actually lead me to the right component

navbar.component.ts

```
  @Component({
  selector: 'navbar',
  template: `<ul>
    <li><a href="#red">Red</a></li>
    <li><a href="#blue">Blue</a></li>
  </ul>`
})
export class NavbarComponent {
  constructor() { }
}
```

red.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'red',
  template: '<div id="red">Red Component</div>'
})
export class RedComponent {
  constructor() { }
}
```

blue.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'blue',
  template: '<div id="blue">Blue Component</div>'
})
export class BlueComponent {
  constructor() { }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<navbar></navbar>
<red></red>
<blue></blue>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } '@angular/router'; 
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { RedComponent } from './red/red.component';
import { BlueComponent } from './blue/blue.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    RedComponent
    BlueComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: What was the result of your research? And do you have `routing.module`? Also you should be using `routerLink` instead of `href`

Comment: It should work but won't have any effect in this example.

Answer (score 0):

To hyperlink to component's template, you need to assign an `id` attribute.  You can do so by using [`@HostBinding`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37965647/hostbinding-and-hostlistener-what-do-they-do-and-what-are-they-for) -

```
@Component({
  selector: 'red',
  template: '<div id="red">Red Component</div>'
})
export class RedComponent {
  @HostBinding('id') id = 'red';
  constructor() { }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'blue',
  template: '<div id="blue">Blue Component</div>'
})
export class BlueComponent {
  @HostBinding('id') id = 'red';
  constructor() { }
}
```

Refer [@HostBinding and @HostListener: what do they do and what are they for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37965647/hostbinding-and-hostlistener-what-do-they-do-and-what-are-they-for)  for more details