# Add class to body on Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have three components. These are HomeComponent, SignInComponent and AppComponent. My Home Page (HomeComponent) is showing when the application opened. I clicked the "Sign In" button by signin page opens.I want "signin-page" class to body while opening it.

How can I do it?

```
// AppComponent
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app',
  template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>'
})
export class AppComponent {}

// SignInComponent
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'signin',
    templateUrl: './signin.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./signin.component.css']
})
export class SignInComponent {}

// HomeComponent
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html'
})
export class HomeComponent { }

// Part of index.html
<body>
<app>
    <div class="spinner">
        <div class="bounce1"></div>
        <div class="bounce2"></div>
        <div class="bounce3"></div>
    </div>
</app>
</body>
```

Comment: I guess it would be much easier if you give every component container that will have dynamic class. Then you can add it really easily...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can change your root selector to `body` and then use `HostBinding` decorator

```
@Component({
  selector: 'body',
  template: `<child></child>`
})
export class AppComponent {
  @HostBinding('class') public cssClass = 'class1';
}

@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: `<button (click)="setClass()">Set class</button>`
})
export class ChildComponent {
  constructor(private rootComp: AppComponent) {  }
  setClass() {
    this.rootComp.cssClass = 'class2';
  }
}
```

Comment: That's crafty! 

Comment: You saved my day. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: It would seem to me that if you did this, you would also want to remove the `body` tag from the index.html... No?

Comment: ...And this would introduce tslint errors, as the selection doesn't have a prefix. Not a problem necessarily, but I try to keep my code free of linting errors.

Comment: @BBaysingerb why remove? Angular will replace contents of body. To fix tslint error you can use `// tslint:disable-next-line `

Answer (score 9):

1. If part of your application is in Angular, then you can do this:

```
let body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
body.classList.remove("className");   //remove the class
body.classList.add("className");   //add the class
```

2. I'll prefer answer given by @Yurzui if the whole frontend is in Angular.

Comment: This was the cleanest and quickest solution for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Angular2 doesn't provide any built in way to modify DOM elements outside the root component (except the `<title>`).

```
querySelector('body').classList.add('signin-page');
querySelector('body').classList.remove('signin-page');
```

or

```
@Component(
  selector: 'body',
  templateUrl: 'app_element.html'
)
class AppElement {
  @HostBinding('class.fixed') 
  bool isFixed = true;
}
```

See also

- [How do I add a class to a given element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507138/how-do-i-add-a-class-to-a-given-element)
- [Angular 2.x bind class on body tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34430666/angular-2-x-bind-class-on-body-tag/34430979#34430979)

Comment: This will break server side rendering.

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer I'm using `@hostbinding` as you are here but my CSS triggers for a split second regardless of the boolean.

Comment: @BenRacicot what does "triggers for a split second" mean exactly. Can't imagine that it does anything but adding the class.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I'm adding an active class to body whenever my bool is true. However the css for `.active` triggers whenever the app loads and goes away immediately afterwards. When I remove `@HostBinding('class') private page = 'active';` the css is not triggered. Just stumped.

Comment: Binding to `class` can be brittle and it's something different than binding to `class.active`. Perhaps you can reproduce in Plunker?

Answer (score 1):

Simple you can do this to add a class to body

```
document.body.classList.add('signin-page');
```