# Angular 2 How to change component <body> background color for each component individually

Tags: css, angular

I have component A and component B.

I want component A  background color to be black.

I want component B  background color to be yellow.

If I modify the  bg color inside the main style.css then that color will be set globally in my app.

*If I try to modify the  bg color inside the component css file the body bg color will not be affected.*

Is there a way to modify the  bg color for each component individually when they load ?

Comment: Sure. If your question would be a bit more specific it would probably be easy to provide an answer.

Comment: This question is specific for Angular 2, and not that much more to add, you have 2 components  and  I want to modify the body background color when  you change the component.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

```
@Component({... }) 
class MyComponent {   constructor() {
  this.bgColor = this.getRandomColor();   }

  @HostBinding('style.background-color')    
  bgColor;

  getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;   
  } 
}
```

**Thanks for downvoting my answer because of the poor question title**

Check instead other answers
- [Style html,body from web component (Angular 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34881401/style-html-body-from-web-component-angular-2/34892496#34892496)
- [Add class to body on Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39971762/add-class-to-body-on-angular2/39971815#39971815)
- [Angular 2.x bind class on body tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34430666/angular-2-x-bind-class-on-body-tag/34430979#34430979)
- ...

Comment: Allow me a few moments to test it, thanks for the answer

Comment: But this is the `background-color` of the component. Not the `background-color` of the **body**. Isn't it? 

Comment: If you make the component 100% height and width it's basically the same. Otherwise just use `document.body.style ... = 'xxx'`