# How to add style to body from component dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to add `style="overflow:hidden"` in `body` tag dynamically from component on click if a button. 
On click of this `<a>` `isWriteEmail` will be true and at that time it should add the `overflow:hidden` to body

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)"
    class="mail-ac-ico"
    (click)="appComponent.isWriteEmail = true;"
    data-toggle="tooltip"
    tooltip="Compose"
    title="Compose">
    <img src="assets/images/icons/icon-open-email.png"
                            alt="email icon">
</a>
```

tried this
`<body *ngIf="isWriteEmail" style="overflow: hidden;">` didn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add class to body on Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39971762/add-class-to-body-on-angular2)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a class:

```
.overflowHidden {
    overflow: hidden
}
```

Then, in the template:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)"
    class="mail-ac-ico"
    (click)="appComponent.isWriteEmail = true;"
    [class.overflowHidden]="appComponent.isWriteEmail"
    data-toggle="tooltip"
    tooltip="Compose"
    title="Compose">
    <img src="assets/images/icons/icon-open-email.png" alt="email icon">
</a>
```

Comment: adding class here won't work, need to add overflow to `body`