# Angular2 add class to body tag

Tags: angular

How can I add a **class** to the **body** tag without making the **body** as the app selector and using host binding?

I tried the using the Renderer but it changes the whole body

[Angular 2.x bind class on body tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34430666/angular-2-x-bind-class-on-body-tag)

I'm working on a big angular2 app and changing the root selector will impact a lot of code, I will have to change a lot of code

My use case is this:

When I open a modal component (created dynamically) I want the document scrollbar to hide

Comment: Actually if you work with js within html page what is the problem with using `document.body.className|classList`?

Comment: haha if only it was that simple :) but it's a bad practice to access dom directly

Comment: You can write a big wrapper that will be executed several second and at the end added `class` to `body`. If you are not going to use server rendering or web worker what you're afraid of?

Comment: so there's no better solution than this ?

Comment: I can't understand these abusive people who downvote and close questions   for no valid reason

Comment: I didn't downvote

Comment: Just a question, Angular is designed as a component architecture. Why do you need to change the body and not the top component app that everything is inside it ?

Comment: I'm working on a big angular2 app and changing the root selector will impact a lot of code, >I will have to change a lot of code

Comment: Why change the body tag? Background color? Top level 'modernizer style' css classes?

Comment: There are [3 great examples to skin this cat](http://diguphere.com/how-to-add-or-remove-class-to-body-tag-in-angular/) listed here. (helped me a lot)

Answer (score 284, accepted):

I would love to comment. But due to missing reputation I write an answer.
Well I know two possibilities to solve this issue.

1. Inject the Global Document. Well it might not be the best practice as I don't know if nativescript etc supports that. But it is at least better than use pure JS.

```js
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {}

ngOnInit(){
   this.document.body.classList.add('test');
}
```

Well and perhaps even better. You could inject the renderer or renderer 2 (on NG4) and add the class with the renderer.

```js
export class myModalComponent implements OnDestroy {

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer) {
    this.renderer.setElementClass(document.body, 'modal-open', true);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.renderer.setElementClass(document.body, 'modal-open', false);
  }
}
```

**EDIT FOR ANGULAR4:**

```js
import { Component, OnDestroy, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

export class myModalComponent implements OnDestroy {

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {
    this.renderer.addClass(document.body, 'modal-open');
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.renderer.removeClass(document.body, 'modal-open');
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I think using the rendrer is the best solution

Comment: In case anyone wondering where to get DOCUMENT, that's:
`import { DOCUMENT } from  '@angular/platform-browser' `

Comment: The Renderer solution is much better. 

In Angular 4, Renderer has been deprecated and replaced with Renderer2.

The code would have to change to:

`this.renderer.addClass(document.body, 'modal-open');`

and `this.renderer.removeClass(document.body, 'modal-open');`

Comment: Also, `@Inject(DOCUMENT)` is no longer needed in the constructor

Comment: If you're using ng4 with renderer2, the methods have been renamed to a more explicit `addClass` and `removeClass`. Documentation here: https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2

Comment: This won't work server-side as there's no `document` there.

Comment: As an update to @Neph : importing DOCUMENT from platform-browser is deprecated. Use @angular/common instead.

Comment: you have to `import { Component, OnInit,Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';`

Comment: minor addition: do the addClass stuff in the ngOnit. Better testable AND, i remove the modal on close. So the oninit is called each time anyway. And the constructor might be invoked in different situations (I inject the modal component through a service, that will cause the add class to fire early)

Comment: How am I supposed to instantiate this class? I am expecting to create it like `dialog = new Dialog();`, so it complains about the two missing parameters.

Comment: thanks, @PieterDeBie very important note for those who choose to use the Document method

Answer (score 77):

I think the best way to do it is a combination of both approaches by DaniS above: Using the renderer to actually set / remove the class, but also using the document injector, so it is not strongly dependant on the `window.document` but that can be replaced dynamically (e.g. when rendering server-side). So the whole code would look like this:

```js
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, Inject, OnDestroy, OnInit, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Component({ /* ... */ })
export class MyModalComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    constructor (
        @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document,
        private renderer: Renderer2,
    ) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.renderer.addClass(this.document.body, 'embedded-body');
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.renderer.removeClass(this.document.body, 'embedded-body');
    }
}
```