# Apply class to body tag in angular 2 app

Tags: angular

I have an Agular 2 app and on the homepage I want to change the background color on the body tag. Each page has it's own component, but since the body tag is outside app-root I can't add a class to it. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 add class to body tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43542373/angular2-add-class-to-body-tag)

Comment: I couldnt get that to work, so I just used plain javascript to add a class
document.body.className += " homepage-background";