# How can I apply different (full page) backgrounds for different Angular 5 pages?

Tags: html, css, angular, single-page-application, angular5

Currently I am using Angular 5 to make an SPA.

I want to fill the entire screen with a background (not just one component) but I want different backgrounds for each page, how can I achieve this?

I have tried this code in the component.css of the concerning page (for example 
 home.component.css):

```
body {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

(using background-color as an example)

Using this method, I thought I could override the main body background per component but it does not seem to work, the page remains empty.

I would appreciate any help you can give me, thanks in advance.

Comment: write your body css `background-color` code in css of every component, for example you have about and contact page so for about do it in `about.component.css` and for contact do it in `contact.component.css` ..... if normal one did not work try this `body{background-color: aqua !important;}`

Comment: for global styling use "**styles.css**"

Comment: @RajnishRajput this does not work for me.

Comment: @PrasanthS It is not really global since every page has a different background.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your issue is that when you add

```
body {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

to your component css, Angular rewrites it to something like

```
body[_ngcontent-c0] {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

You can see it in dev tools if you check. Because of this, the style does not get attached to the body. You can use Renderer2 to change the body style for each component. For example:

```
import { Component, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './home.component.css' ]
})
export class HomeComponent  {
  name = 'Home';

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {
    this.renderer.setStyle(document.body, 'background-color', 'yellow');
  }
}
```

Similar Question: [Angular2 add class to body tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43542373/angular2-add-class-to-body-tag/43552385)
Angular documentation: https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2
Hope this helps.

Comment: @Mike - Accessing the browser specific APIs including window, document and other DOM APIs is a bad practice in Angular. And if you use Angular Universal for better user experience and SEO, this use of document object will be a problem

Answer (score 2):

Add the following component in all the components that need background color. The color to be used can be passed in the input attribute:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-bg',
  templateUrl: './bg.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bg.component.scss']
})
export class BgComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() bgColor = 'red';

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  public getBgColor() {
    return {
      'background-color': this.bgColor
    };
  }
}
```

Here is the CSS bg.component.scss:

```
.bg {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

And the template bg.component.html:

```
<div class="bg" [ngStyle]="getBgColor()"></div>
```

Finally in all the components that need background color, add this:

```
<app-bg [bgColor]="'blue'"></app-bg>
```