# how to select HTML tag from component CSS

Tags: css, angular

My `app.component.html` is as below, `app-login` is a Component

```
<app-login></app-login>
```

and If I write below code in `login.component.scss`

```
html, body{
  height: 100% !important; 
}
```

I get below `style`

```
html[_ngcontent-c3], body[_ngcontent-c3] {
  height: 100% !important; 
}
```

How do I target `HTML` from component, please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Renderer2` to change the html and body style from component. For example:

```
import { Component, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './home.component.css' ]
})
export class HomeComponent  {
  name = 'Home';

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {
    this.renderer.setStyle(document.body, 'background-color', 'yellow');   
    this.renderer.setStyle(ddocument.getElementsByTagName('html')[0], 'background-color', 'blue');
  }
}
```

See my answer to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48718382/9262488

Comment: thanks @Nik648. for those who want to explore `Renderer2`, here is a reference https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-4-renderer2-example#selectRootElement