# Add or remove class to/from body based on route component in angular 7

Tags: html, angular

Add or remove class to/from body tag based on the route component in angular 7

for eg.

if path is /login i need to add a class 'abc' to body
if path is something i don't add any class to body

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 add class to body tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43542373/angular2-add-class-to-body-tag)

Comment: Why do you want to do that, because of special layout on login page? In this case you can also use different layouts via different route-components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to do the following on your component :

```
constructor(
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any
) {
    this.document.body.classList.add('abc');
}
```

Comment: how do i remove this class when I move to any other component. I don't want to remove it individually in all other components. Is there an easy way

Comment: You use AngularRouter to have a base component that all your childrens will be injected in (see https://angular.io/guide/router#a-crisis-center-with-child-routeshttps://angular.io/guide/router#a-crisis-center-with-child-routes) and in this component you addClass on ngOnInit and you remove it in ngOnDestroy

Comment: @user8765332  `this.document.body.classList.toggle('abc', someCondition);` ([Reference](https://alligator.io/js/classlist/))