# Angular components own backgrounds caching

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, background-image

I am trying to make an Agular app, and I want certain components to have certain background images. So I tried in the .ts files

> encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None

And in the .scss file

> body { background-image:url (...) }

The problem is that when I move from one page to another the background of the first page is on the second one until I hit refresh. ( I tried to put !important also :D)

Thanks for your time!

Comment: `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` makes your component CSS global. Do not change the style of `body` from components, it will become maintenance headache.

Comment: I understand that now, but I asked how can I change background-images without it:d

Comment: @Andrei Remove `encapsulation` to get rid of the problem and to change the background image of `body` read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43552385/11719787)