# angular13: how to manually add scss files by condition to index.html?

Tags: angular, angular13

I want to add this import

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/sass/style.scss">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/sass/plugins.scss">
```

by condition to index.html in angular

but it's not work

I want to change style to rtl or ltr by selected language so i change import scss file in index.html

style rtl is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/sass/style.angular.scss">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/style.rtl.css">
```

style ltr is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/sass/style.scss">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/sass/plugins.scss">
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume the contents of `style.angular.scss`

```
.test {
    display: block;
}
```

Lets assume the contents of `style.scss`

```
.test1 {
    display: flex;
}
```

modify it so that there is a parent class wrapping each of the different styles
so the new code will be

`style.angular.scss`

```
.body-ltr-class {
    .test {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

`style.scss`

```
.body-rtl-class {
    .test1 {
        display: flex;
    }
}
```

Now you can import all imports and styles can be applied based on the parent class (either `body-ltr-class` or `body-rtl-class`)

For adding class to the body tag, please use the below stack overflow answer

[add class to body tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43542373/angular2-add-class-to-body-tag)

Answer (score 0):

Please trying using logical properties in css, since it eliminates the need to write 2 different stylesheets for direction. e.g: instead of saying `padding-right: 1rem;` you can say `padding-inline-start: 1rem;`. The `padding-inline-start` looks at the direction your line starts(in this case you are in rtl mode) so `padding-inline-start` is equal to `padding-right`.

But if you insist that you want to load different styles based on your language, you have to follow these steps:

- In your angular.json(or project.json) add these styles in this format:

  ```
                "styles": [
                {
                    "input": "style-url",
                    "bundleName": "some-name",
                    "inject": false
                },
                "styles": [
                {
                    "input": "style-url2",
                    "bundleName": "some-name2",
                    "inject": false
                },
            ],
  ```

As you can see, these styles have `"inject": false`, meaning they will not be added to html's link section by default. You are just saying that you are gonna have 2 lazy loaded files in this part.

next you have add these styles to your html.
Make a new service, in that service you have to write a code like this:

```
        const style = document.createElement('link');
        style.rel = 'stylesheet';
        style.href = `${style-name}.css`;
        style.id = this.${some-id};

        document.head.append(style);
```

name of your style should be the name you assigned them in the previous step.
And you should a conditional state that which style should be added.