# conditionally apply css class to body in angular 5

Tags: angular, layout

I'm using angular 5 for my project. Where I'm using 2 different layouts as **public (login page) & secure (other pages)**. I want to **apply css class to `<body>` in index.html conditionally**. That is,

> The `class="fixed-nav sticky-footer bg-light"` should be applied to `<body>` only on visiting Secure Layout, but not for Public Layout.

But I'm unable to achieve that. Please help me to tackle it.

Here is my code -

***secure.component.html -***

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

***public.component.html -***

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

***app.component.html -***

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

***index.html -***

```
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34430666/angular-2-x-bind-class-on-body-tag/34430979#34430979