# Angular 2 change live varible - set page title from multiple components

Tags: typescript, angular

I need to update a variable in another component.

```
import {Component, EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core';
import {Input, Output} from "angular2/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'title-page',
    template: `<span>{{tp}}</span>`,
})

export class TitlePage {
    private tp;

    ngOnInit(){
        this.tp = 'Dashboard';
    }

    public setTitle(title:string) {
        this.tp = title;
    }
}
```

How routing this component need live change title in different component:

```
import {Component, Inject, forwardRef} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';
import {NgClass} from 'angular2/common';
import {AppComponent} from "../app.component";
import {TitlePage} from "../components-shared/top-panel/titlePage";

@Component({
    selector: 'main-page',
    styles:[],
    template:`
        <main-page>asd</main-page>
    `,
    directives: [],
    providers: [TitlePage]
})

export class MainPageComponent {

    constructor(private tp:TitlePage){
        this.tp.setTitle('afsdf');
    }

}
```

The title of the component is outside the routing.
EventEmmiter not working...NgZone also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2.x change <title> in head (outside my app)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34422815/angular-2-x-change-title-in-head-outside-my-app)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a service (e.g., `ConfigService`), and put the title inside an object:

```
title = { value: 'Some title here' };
```

Then inject the service into your TitlePage component and bind to the `title.value` property:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'title-page',
    template: `<span>{{title.value}}</span>`,
})
export class TitlePage {
  constructor(private _configService: ConfigService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.title = this._configService.title;
  }
```

Also inject the service into any other component that needs to change the title.  Since `title` is an object, all of the components will reference the same object.  So, you should be able to simply change the `value` property from any component, and the title should update:

```
export class MainPageComponent {
  constructor(private _configService: ConfigService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this._configService.title.value = 'some new title';
  }
```

Comment: thanks!!! But not, title: { value: 'Some title here' }; -> title = { value: 'Some title here' };

Answer (score 1):

Why not use **Angular's Title Service**?

Here's an example

In your entry file

```
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    Title
    }
]).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

later in your components

```
 import { Component ,Inject, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
 import { Title } from "@angular/platform-browser";
 @Component({
    template: '<h1>Home page!</h1>'
 })

 export class Home implements OnInit{
   ngOnInit() {
        console.log("App component loaded");
         this.titleService.setTitle( "home" );
    }
   public constructor(@Inject(Title) private titleService: Title ) {}
     setTitle( newTitle: string) {
     this.titleService.setTitle( newTitle );
    }        
}
```

For more detaile read [angulor.io/title](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/set-document-title.html)